# Is there a string math evaluator in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net

If I have a string with a valid math expression such as:

```
String s = "1 + 2 * 7";
```

Is there a built in library/function in .NET that will parse and evaluate that expression for me and return the result? In this case 15.

Comment: Not a built in one. But there is a pretty comprehensive one [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/pwelter34/archive/2007/05/05/calculator-net-calculator-that-evaluates-math-expressions.aspx).

Comment: See also, [Is it possible to translate a user-entered mathematical equation into C# code at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234217/is-it-possible-to-translate-a-user-entered-mathematical-equation-into-c-code-at)

Comment: You can use [The expression evaluator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/eval3.aspx) (Eval function in 100% managed .NET)

Comment: I just created a code-only solution to evaluating mathematical expressions in C#. You can see the code at http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/algorithms/a-c-expression-evaluator.

Comment: This library seems to have some bugs.

Comment: It may be worth checking out my answer here, which uses Mono.CSharp.Evaluator and should be capable of doing what you require and then some. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979423/expression-evaluator-for-c-python-ruby/10532125#10532125

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# evaluating string "3\*(4+2)" yield int 18](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/c-sharp-evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You could add a reference to Microsoft Script Control Library (COM) and use code like this to evaluate an expression.  (Also works for JScript.)

```
Dim sc As New MSScriptControl.ScriptControl()
sc.Language = "VBScript"
Dim expression As String = "1 + 2 * 7"
Dim result As Double = sc.Eval(expression)
```

**Edit** - C# version.

```
MSScriptControl.ScriptControl sc = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControl();
sc.Language = "VBScript";
string expression = "1 + 2 * 7";
object result = sc.Eval(expression);            
MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```

**Edit** - The ScriptControl is a COM object.  In the "Add reference" dialog of the project select the "COM" tab and scroll down to "Microsoft Script Control 1.0" and select ok.

Answer (score 95):

Strange that this famous and old question has not an answer that suggests the  builtin [`DataTable.Compute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx)-"trick". Here it is.

```
double result = Convert.ToDouble(new DataTable().Compute("1 + 2 * 7", null));
```

The following arithmetic operators are supported in expressions:

```
+ (addition)
- (subtraction)
* (multiplication)
/ (division)
% (modulus)
```

More informations: [`DataColumn.Expression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx) at *Expression Syntax*.

Answer (score 30):

Have you seen http://ncalc.codeplex.com ?

It's extensible, fast (e.g. has its own cache) enables you to provide custom functions and varaibles at run time by handling EvaluateFunction/EvaluateParameter events. Example expressions it can parse:

```
Expression e = new Expression("Round(Pow(Pi, 2) + Pow([Pi2], 2) + X, 2)"); 

  e.Parameters["Pi2"] = new Expression("Pi * Pi"); 
  e.Parameters["X"] = 10; 

  e.EvaluateParameter += delegate(string name, ParameterArgs args) 
    { 
      if (name == "Pi") 
      args.Result = 3.14; 
    }; 

  Debug.Assert(117.07 == e.Evaluate());
```

It also handles unicode & many data type natively. It comes with an antler file if you want to change the grammer. There is also a fork which supports MEF to load new functions.

Comment: Great library.  Also available on NUGET

Comment: This is what I used for my differential equation solver which took a user's input. The question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32333134/turn-user-input-string-into-mathematical-function/32378818#32378818)

Comment: The latest is at https://github.com/ncalc/ncalc , NCalcSync on NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/NCalcSync

Answer (score 28):

For anybody developing in C# on Silverlight here's a pretty neat trick that I've just discovered that allows evaluation of an expression by calling out to the Javascript engine:

```
double result = (double) HtmlPage.Window.Eval("15 + 35");
```

Comment: As this evaluates arbitrary Javascript code, you probably want to be sure to sanitize your input and make sure you're not directly displaying the result.  (I would think this would be a good way to introduce XSS without realizing it)

Comment: Try entering numbers with a leading zero, the result isn't reliable. "054 + 6" gives you 50 for example.

Comment: @djerry, that is because numbers with a leading zero are considered octal by JS's evaluator, and octal 054 equals decimal 44.

Answer (score 17):

Yet another option now that Roslyn is available:

You can use CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting library for this.

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using System;

namespace ExpressionParser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Demonstrate evaluating C# code
            var result = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync("System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) > System.DateTime.Now").Result;
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());

            //Demonstrate evaluating simple expressions
            var result2 = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(" 5 * 7").Result;
            Console.WriteLine(result2);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

nuget packages:

```
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Common" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
```

Answer (score 15):

Actually there is kind of a built in one - you can use the XPath namespace!
Although it requires that you reformat the string to confirm with XPath notation. I've used a method like this to handle simple expressions:

```
    public static double Evaluate(string expression)
    {
        var xsltExpression = 
            string.Format("number({0})", 
                new Regex(@"([\+\-\*])").Replace(expression, " ${1} ")
                                        .Replace("/", " div ")
                                        .Replace("%", " mod "));

        return (double)new XPathDocument
            (new StringReader("<r/>"))
                .CreateNavigator()
                .Evaluate(xsltExpression);
    }
```

Answer (score 14):

Initially I used the c# wrapper for [muparser](http://muparser.beltoforion.de/). This was very fast. The only faster solution I know is [exprtk](http://www.partow.net/programming/exprtk/index.html). If you are looking for other solutions you can checkout the [benchmark](https://github.com/ArashPartow/math-parser-benchmark-project).

But in case of .Net you can use the builtin support to compile code at runtime. The idea is to have a "template" source file as e.g. embedded resource where you can replace the formula for the evaluation. Then you pass this prepared class-source-code to the compiler.

A basic template could look like this:

```
public class CSCodeEvaler
{
    public double EvalCode()
    {
        return last = Convert.ToDouble(%formula%);
    }

    public double last = 0;
    public const double pi = Math.PI;
    public const double e = Math.E;
    public double sin(double value) { return Math.Sin(value); }
    public double cos(double value) { return Math.Cos(value); }
    public double tan(double value) { return Math.Tan(value); }
    ...
```

Notice the %formula% where the expression will be put in.

To compile use the class CSharpCodeProvider. I do not want to put in the complete source here. But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188882/compile-and-run-dynamic-code-without-generating-exe) might help:

After you have the in memory assembly loaded you can create an instance of your class and call EvalCode.

Answer (score 11):

Recently I was using mXparser, which is a math parser library for .NET and JAVA. mXparser supports basic formulas as well as very fancy / complicated ones (including variables, functions, operators, iteration and recursion).

https://mxparser.codeplex.com/

https://mathparser.org/

A few usage examples:

Example 1:

```
Expression e = new Expression("1+2*7 + (sin(10) - 2)/3");
double v = e.calculate();
```

Example 2:

```
Argument x = new Argument("x = 5");
Expression e = new Expression("2*x+3", x);
double v = e.calculate();
```

Example 3:

```
Function f = new Function("f(x,y) = sin(x) / cos(y)");
Expression e = new Expression("f(pi, 2*pi) - 2", f);
double v = e.calculate();
```

Found recently - in case you would like to try the syntax (and see the advanced use case) you can download the [Scalar](https://scalarmath.org) [Calculator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mathparser.scalar.lite) [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mathparser.scalar.pro) that is powered by mXparser.

Best regards

Answer (score 6):

If you need very simple thing you can use the `DataTable` :-)

```vb
Dim dt As New DataTable
dt.Columns.Add("A", GetType(Integer))
dt.Columns.Add("B", GetType(Integer))
dt.Columns.Add("C", GetType(Integer))
dt.Rows.Add(New Object() {12, 13, DBNull.Value})

Dim boolResult As Boolean = dt.Select("A>B-2").Length > 0

dt.Columns.Add("result", GetType(Integer), "A+B*2+ISNULL(C,0)")
Dim valResult As Object = dt.Rows(0)("result")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Math-Expression-Evaluator](https://github.com/Giorgi/Math-Expression-Evaluator) library that I am author of. It supports simple expressions such as `2.5+5.9`, `17.89-2.47+7.16`, `5/2/2+1.5*3+4.58`, expressions with parentheses `(((9-6/2)*2-4)/2-6-1)/(2+24/(2+4))` and expressions with variables:

```
var a = 6;
var b = 4.32m;
var c = 24.15m;
var engine = new ExpressionEvaluator();
engine.Evaluate("(((9-a/2)*2-b)/2-a-1)/(2+c/(2+4))", new { a, b, c});
```

You can also pass parameters as named variables:

```
dynamic dynamicEngine = new ExpressionEvaluator();

var a = 6;
var b = 4.5m;
var c = 2.6m;

dynamicEngine.Evaluate("(c+b)*a", a: 6, b: 4.5, c: 2.6);
```

It supports .Net Standard 2.0 so can be used from .Net Core as well as .Net Full Framework projects and it doesn't have any external dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

I would also have a look at Jace (https://github.com/pieterderycke/Jace). Jace is a high performance math parser and calculation engine that supports all the .NET flavors (.NET 4.x, Windows Phone, Windows Store, ...). Jace is also available through NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jace

Answer (score 3):

A simple math parser is quite easy to build, and requires only a few lines of code:

Take this flexible example:

```
class RPN
{
    public static double Parse( Stack<string> strStk )
    {
        if (strStk == null || strStk.Count == 0 )
        {
            return 0;
        }
        Stack<double> numStk = new Stack<double>();
        double result = 0;

        Func<double, double> op = null;
        while (strStk.Count > 0)
        {
            var s = strStk.Pop();
            switch (s)
            {
                case "+":
                    op = ( b ) => { return numStk.Pop() + b; };
                    break;
                case "-":
                    op = ( b ) => { return numStk.Pop() - b; };
                    break;
                case "*":
                    op = ( b ) => { return numStk.Pop() * b; };
                    break;
                case "/":
                    op = ( b ) => { return numStk.Pop() / b; };
                    break;

                default:
                    double.TryParse(s, NumberStyles.Any, out result);
                    if (numStk.Count > 0)
                    {
                        result = op(result);
                    }
                    numStk.Push(result);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}

....
var str = " 100.5 + 300.5 - 100 * 10 / 100";    
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"\s", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Stack<string> strStk = new Stack<string>(
     Regex.Split(str, @"([()*+\/-])", RegexOptions.Multiline).Reverse()
);
RPN.Parse(strStk);
```

To enable precedence by bracketing  a stack of stacks will suffice, such as archived by recursion. Anything between brackets is put on a new stack.
Finally you can support math operations in a clean readable fashion by lambdas.

Comment: You might want to verify your answer. `100.5 + 300.5 - 100 * 10 / 100 = 30.1` vs `391`

Comment: Your sample will always fail in the default branch of your switch statement                   result = op(result); <- op is null

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in solution, but there are easy ways to make it work.

There are at least two good new solutions for the problem now: using symbolic algebra [AngouriMath](https://github.com/asc-community/AngouriMath) or general purpose algorithm library [Towel](https://github.com/ZacharyPatten/Towel).

#### AngouriMath

You can do

```cs
using AngouriMath;
Entity expr = "1 + 2 + sqrt(2)";
var answer = (double)expr.EvalNumerical();
```

(by default it computes in high-precision, might be useful too)

Or compile it

```cs
Entity expr = "1 + 2 + sqrt(2) + x + y";
Func<double, double, double> someFunc = expr.Compile<double, double, double>("x", "y");
Console.WriteLine(someFunc(3, 5));
```

so that it could be used in time-critical code.

#### Towel

Here you can do

```cs
using Towel.Mathematics;
var expression = Symbolics.Parse<double>("(2 + 2 * 2 - (2 ^ 4)) / 2");
Console.WriteLine(expression.Simplify());
```

which would directly compute your expression into `double`.

#### Installation

Both can be installed via Nuget: [AngouriMath](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AngouriMath), [Towel](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Towel).

Answer (score 1):

I implemented an expression parser a few years ago and had published a version of it in [GitHub](https://github.com/RushuiGuan/expression) and [Nuget:Albatross.Expression](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Albatross.Expression/) recently.  It contains a ExecutionContext class that can evaluate a set of expressions such as:

- MV = Price * Qty;
- Price = (Bid + Ask)/2;
- Bid = .6;
- Ask = .8;

It also has built in circular reference check which is useful to avoid a stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

## MathNet.Symbolics

```
using System;
using static MathNet.Symbolics.SymbolicExpression;
using static System.Console;
using static System.Numerics.Complex;
using Complex = System.Numerics.Complex;

namespace MathEvaluator
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly Complex i = ImaginaryOne;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var z = Variable("z");
            Func<Complex, Complex> f = Parse("z * z").CompileComplex(nameof(z));
            Complex c = 1 / 2 - i / 3;
            WriteLine(f(c));


            var x = Variable("x");
            Func<double, double> g = Parse("x * x + 5 * x + 6").Compile(nameof(x));
            double a = 1 / 3.0;
            WriteLine(g(a));
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to load

```
<PackageReference Include="MathNet.Symbolics" Version="0.20.0" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try my matheval library on github

repo: https://github.com/matheval/expression-evaluator-c-sharp

nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/org.matheval/

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace CalcExp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double res = Evaluate("4+5/2-1");

            Console.WriteLine(res);

        }

        public static double Evaluate(string expression)
        {
            var xsltExpression =
                string.Format("number({0})",
                    new Regex(@"([\+\-\*])").Replace(expression, " ${1} ")
                                            .Replace("/", " div ")
                                            .Replace("%", " mod "));

// ReSharper disable PossibleNullReferenceException
            return (double)new XPathDocument
                (new StringReader("<r/>"))
                    .CreateNavigator()
                    .Evaluate(xsltExpression);
// ReSharper restore PossibleNullReferenceException
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: -1: Just merge this into @cbp answer. There is ZERO need to have two answers which are fundamentally identical when we can have one fantastic answer.

Answer (score 0):

Flee 
Fast Lightweight Expression Evaluator

https://flee.codeplex.com

Language Reference

- ArithmeticOperators  Example: a*2 + b ^ 2 - 100 % 5
- ComparisonOperators  Example: a <> 100
- AndOrXorNotOperators  Example (logical): a > 100 And Not b = 100
- ShiftOperators  Example: 100 >> 2
- Concatenation  Example: "abc" + "def"
- Indexing  Example: arr[i + 1] + 100
- Literals
- Casting  Example: 100 + cast(obj, int)
- ConditionalOperator  Example: If(a > 100 and b > 10, "both greater", "less")
- InOperator  Example (List): If(100 in (100, 200, 300, -1), "in", "not in")
- Overloaded Operators On Types

Example :

```
Imports Ciloci.Flee
Imports Ciloci.Flee.CalcEngine
Imports System.Math
```

---

```
    Dim ec As New Ciloci.Flee.ExpressionContext
    Dim ex As IDynamicExpression
    ec.Imports.AddType(GetType(Math))

    ec.Variables("a") = 10            
    ec.Variables("b") = 40               
    ex = ec.CompileDynamic("a+b")

    Dim evalData    
    evalData = ex.Evaluate()
    Console.WriteLine(evalData)
```

The output : 50