# Dynamically execute string as code in C#

Tags: c#, reflection, codedom

I need to convert string to executable code. The `string` is in `foreach` statement.

```
foreach (InsuredItem _i in p.InsuredItems)
{
    string formula = "(_i.PremiumRate/100)*SumAssured";
    _i.Premium = (Execute formula);
}
```

The formula is loaded from setup. this is just a demonstration. I need to execute the string in foreach loop.
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34758802/how-to-execute-my-string-as-code

Comment: http://ncalc.codeplex.com/

Comment: You want only formula or result?

Comment: I need the result. Which will be decimal value

Comment: Below is the code which i have tried but still not working:                `Expression ev = new Expression(formula);
                ev.Parameters["_i"] = _i;
                _i.Premium = ev.Evaluate().ToDecimal();`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that your formula is valid C# code and that it uses a known set of local variables (so that you can create a "globals" type containing all of them), you should be able to use [Roslyn scripting API](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples) to do this:

```
public class Globals
{
    public InsuredItem _i;
    public decimal SumAssured;
}

…

string formula = "(_i.PremiumRate/100)*SumAssured";
var script = CSharpScript.Create<decimal>(formula, globalsType: typeof(Globals))
    .CreateDelegate();

foreach (InsuredItem _i in p.InsuredItems)
{
    _i.Premium = await script(new Globals { _i = _i, SumAssured = SumAssured });
}
```

Comment: BTW, having local variable names start with underscore is unusual in C#, you might want to consider using common naming conventions.

Comment: Am getting 'The name 'VVC' does not exist in the current context' at var script = CSharpScript.Create<decimal>(formula, globalsType: typeof(Globals))
    .CreateDelegate();

Comment: @SebastianKilonzo Well, what is VVC? It has to be something specific to your code. Is it something in the formula?

Comment: Thanks svic... you are right, it was something with my variables. Its now working