# Regex to Group Different Parts of a Repeating Pattern

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently looking at building a calculation parser tool for a Rules Engine project.

The calculation takes the form of a string which I was using string.split(' ') to get into an array of values, separating the values and operators:

```
expression = "5 + 6 - 8"
expression.split(' ');

[0]:5
[1]:+
[2]:6
[3]:-
[4]:8
```

My code uses this array to get the answer 3 - at the moment I'm just doing left to right evaluation and dealing with operator precedence.

I'm looking to extend the calculation string to work with dates - adding or subtracting minutes from a date time, unfortunately my DateTime has a space so I get the result:

```
expression = "12/12/2016 12:00:00 + 30 - 10"
expression.split(' ');

[0]:12/12/2016 
[1]:12:00:00
[2]:+
[3]:30
[4]:-
[5]:10
```

When I really want:

```
[0]:12/12/2016 12:00:00 
[1]:+
[2]:30
[3]:-
[4]:10
```

I was hoping to solve this through a regular expression so I could also validate the string at the same time but unfortunately my knowledge of creating them is limited.

Would anyone have an example of a regular expression, or any suggestions on how I could potentially do this - getting the numbers and operators to be stored separately in an array? or is this not possible with regular expressions? would I be better off using String.Substring() instead to pull out the data?

**edit**
sln solution solved my issue, my final code looked like this:

```
var splitExp = Regex.Split(expression, @"[ ](?:(?=\D)|(?<=\D[ ]))");
```

Which gives:

```
expression = "12/12/2016 12:00:00"
splitExp[0] =  "12/12/2016 12:00:00"

expression = "12/12/2016 12:00:00 + 30 - 10"
splitExp[0] =  "12/12/2016 12:00:00"
splitExp[0] =  "+"
splitExp[0] =  "30"
splitExp[0] =  "-"
splitExp[0] =  "10"
```

Which is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Well, though it sounds too broad, you might try `Regex.Split(expression, @" (?!\d+:)")`. Also, see [*Is there a string math evaluator in .NET?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/is-there-a-string-math-evaluator-in-net)

Comment: ^This. Use negative lookaheads to get your regex to match properly. The given code might not be exactly what OP needs, but it can be used as a starting point because it is at least very close to what OP needs.

Comment: Also, see [*How to parse math expressions in C#*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2853907/how-to-parse-math-expressions-in-c).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I noticed the first post but the answers actually do too much for me - they actually do the calculation whereas I'm just looking to pull out the info from the string - as I'm needing it to build a Lamda expression. The second post however I didn't notice and is very interesting - I will look at this if I need to but operator precedence in at some point. Thanks for the pointers

Answer (score 0):

There are more elegant ways of doing this, but you can always substitute a token in for the space in the date as a way of preprocessing the input and then swap the replacement back out for a space when you process the split index. Example:
replace `(([0-9]{2}/){2}[0-9]{4})( )(([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2})` with `$1@@SPACE@@$4` before you split the string on spaces and then when you process the split string at each index replace `@@SPACE@@` with an actual space before continuing.

Comment: So swapping out spaces that I don't want to be considered spaces with a special character, something like - "12/12/2016@SPACE@12:00:00 + 30 - 10" and then substituting out @SPACE@ for an actual space before parsing. This would work for me - though I agree it wouldn't be the most elegant...