# How to Compile the .cs file into .dll in C#.Net programatically?

Tags: c#-4.0

Can any one help me in converting the .cs file into .dll programmatically?

Comment: This has been asked, sorry I cant find the original question now.

Comment: SO users are donating their free time here so things like 'ASAP' don't quite work...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188882/compile-and-run-dynamic-code-without-generating-exe

Comment: You logged here first time ever and want people to do your job, and fast! That's much more than just being lazy [which SO users quite got used to already]. At least take time to vote up the answers and select one as accepted to give credit to people that didn't get offended and helped you.

Comment: @naugtur: He can't upvote anything until he gets 15 rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`CSharpCodeProvider` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx).

For example:

```
var compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string> { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } });
var options = new CompilerParameters { OutputAssembly = path);
var results = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromFile(options, sourceFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) class.