# C# calling external method (delegate) from within

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-function

I'm generating and executing C# from within a C# program using [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10614752/314056).

As you can see, one can call "Execute" method of the compiled code via `classType.GetMethod("Execute").Invoke(instance, args)`.

The variable `args` is an object array of parameters to be passed to the `Execute` method. I've been able to pass things relatively easy and without issue using this system.

Now here's the big issue... I need to pass a callback function (eg a Delegate) so that the `Execute` method will be able to signal stuff to the main program. I've been trying to pass a typed Delegate that matches the signature, but it failed (wouldn't even run). Next I tried passing a Delegate without specifying the type which also failed (this time it failed at when the call was attempted). I also tried passing it as a normal object and cast it back inside the generated code, but it didn't do anything different.

Since I'm not this much into C#, I think I'm missing something very basic. Also, I don't have a valid test case code...but it shouldn't be too difficult to work with the link I provided above..

See also: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655

Edit: This is some sample code:

```
class CompilerTest {

    private object obj;
    private MethodInfo mtd;

    public void on_log(string type, string message){
        MessageBox.Show(type.ToUpper() + ": " + message);
    }

    public void compile(){
        CodeDomProvider c = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
        CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();

        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.data.dll");
        cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("system.windows.forms.dll");

        cp.CompilerOptions = "/t:library";
        cp.GenerateInMemory = true;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
        sb.AppendLine("using System;");
        sb.AppendLine("using System.Data;");
        sb.AppendLine("using System.Reflection;");
        sb.AppendLine("using System.Windows.Forms;");

        sb.AppendLine("public delegate void LoggerInternal(string type, string message);");

        sb.AppendLine("public class CSCodeEvalCls{");

        sb.AppendLine("  private LoggerInternal log;");

        sb.AppendLine("  public void E(object lgr){");
        sb.AppendLine("    this.log = (RuleLoggerInternal)lgr;");
        sb.AppendLine("  }");

        sb.AppendLine("  private void L(string type, string message){");
        sb.AppendLine("    this.log(type, message);");
        sb.AppendLine("  }");

        sb.AppendLine("}");

        CompilerResults cr = c.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, sb.ToString());
        System.Reflection.Assembly a = cr.CompiledAssembly;

        this.obj = a.CreateInstance("CSCodeEvalCls");
        this.mtd = this.obj.GetType().GetMethod("E");
    }

    public void execute(){
        this.mtd.Invoke(this.obj, new object[]{ this.on_log });
    }

}

CompilerTest test = new CompilerTest();
test.compile();
test.execute();
```

Comment: You should post the code that doesn't work.

Comment: You'll have to show us the code that passes in a delegate as well as the code you are compiling on-the-fly that attempts to execute that delegate.  One or both of those are likely to be the problem.

Comment: OK, ok I'll see what I can do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to pass in a delegate of a different type, and then convert it from inside of the newly-compiled code.

For example, outside of the code you would invoke it like this:

```
this.mtd.Invoke(this.obj, new object[]{ new Action<string, string>(this.on_log) });
```

Now you have a few options about how you handle this from your compiled code.

First, you can forgo defining your own `LoggerInternal` delegate type and just use `Action<string, string>`.

Second, inside of the compiled code you can convert the delegate through this type:

```
public void E(object lgr) {
    this.log = new LoggerInternal((Action<string, string>)lgr);
}
```

Third, if you don't want the compiled code to know what kind of delegate it was passed, you can use `Delegate.CreateDelegate()`:

```
public void E(object lgr) {
    Delegate d = (Delegate)lgr;

    this.log = (LoggerInternal)Delegate.CreateDelegate(
        typeof(LoggerInternal),
        d.Target,
        d.Method);
}
```

Comment: That looks reasonable enough...I'll try this as soon as I get back at work. :D