# Can i Read code from a file and and let that code run in an application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am developing an Desktop Application in WPF using C# .

For the sake of simplicity, Assume my Application has functions which draw lines  in said direction `goleft() , goright() , goforward() , goback() .`

when any of these function is called a line of one inch will be drawn on screen.

I want to make application where user will write code in a file in any editor (say notepad) and  save that file in some fixed format (say .abc or .xyz)

Imaginary Example :

```
   (section_start)

   For(int i = 0 ; i<= 20 ; i++ ) 
    {
      if(i<5)
      goforward();

      else if(i==5)   
       goleft();

      else if(i < 10)
       forward();
        .......
        ........
    }

    (section_End)
```

Can i make application which should be capable of reading this file and execute code which is written in between of (section_start) and (section_End). and only if possible can check for syntax errors too... (Not compulsory).

Please guide me on this issue :

Disclosure : My actual Application is somewhat else and could not discuss here due to my company's rules.

***Thanks to all who replied to my question. Stackoverflow is fantastic site , i have found the roadmap where to go , till today morning i did not have any clue but now i can go ahead , thanks all of you once again 
Will ask question again if i get stucked somewhere***

Comment: Sounds like compiling into a assembly in memory at runtime.

Comment: Do you want a **Parser/Interpreter** or a **JIT Compiler**?

Comment: Similar Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576463/can-i-read-code-from-a-file-and-and-let-that-code-run-in-an-application

Comment: @RuteshMakhijani Are you referring to the same question?

Comment: OP needs to define requirement of parsing or compiling. Either way, there's plenty of resources out there for both.

Comment: @Alvin Wong  The question referred is about similar functionality and contains solution which can work in this scenario also

Comment: @RuteshMakhijani what? It's the exact link to *this* question

Comment: @AlvinWong , I have no idea this requirement came to me today only , Please guide me which is suitable . and show me the road map please

Comment: @RuteshMakhijani , please post the link to that question because you have gave link above of this page only

Comment: @Nidhi Sharma - sorry for the mix up, please find the link to the question I was referring http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments

Comment: @NidhiSharma - I dont know about ur exact requirement, is it required to read code from external file, compile and execute? If yes then you can refer to the inputs and build the code. But if your requirement is to let users specify the diagram elements - referring to points you have mentioned - and not the C# code (i.e. requirement does not mandate users to write C# code - it is one of the implementation option you are evaluating), then I would suggest use XML file or any other notation to accept inputs from file, parse the file and execute the approriate actions in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose CodeDOM or IL Emit

[More help on CodeDOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx)

[More information on IL Generator / Emit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You can read the file content using [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) and get the code you need to execute.

Then you can execute the code using [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188882/compile-and-run-dynamic-code-without-generating-exe):

```
using (Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider foo = 
       new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider())
{
var res = foo.CompileAssemblyFromSource(
    new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters() 
    {  
        GenerateInMemory = true 
    }, 
    "public class FooClass { public string Execute() { return \"output!\";}}"
);

var type = res.CompiledAssembly.GetType("FooClass");

var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

var output = type.GetMethod("Execute").Invoke(obj, new object[] { });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called scripting your application if I understand correctly. C# does not support this out of the box. One thing to look into could be the new Roselyn compiler from Microsoft (it is a new take on the C# compiler, which lets you do just this).

For more info on Roselyn check out:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2011/12/02/introduction-to-the-roslyn-scripting-api.aspx

I've only seen a demo of it, but it looks very promissing, and should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what kind of code you want compiled but here is a [guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655) on how to compile code code with C#.

Answer (score 0):

You could use IronPython to handle the script.

Here's an example of how to do this:

First you need a navigation object to perform the operations on:

```
public class NavigationObject
{
    public int Offset { get; private set; }

    public void GoForwards()
    {
        Offset++;
    }

    public void GoBackwards()
    {
        Offset--;
    }
}
```

Then the code to execute the file:

```
public void RunNavigationScript(string filePath, NavigationObject navObject)
{
    var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    var scope = engine.CreateScope();

    scope.SetVariable("navigation", navObject);
    var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(filePath);
    try
    {
        source.Execute(scope);
    }
    catch(Exception
    {
    }
}
```

The script file can then take the form of something like:

```
for x in range(0,20):
    if x == 5:
        navigation.GoBackwards()
    else:
        navigation.GoForwards()
```