# How do I run a Python script from C#?

Tags: c#, python, .net, ironpython, python.net

This sort of question has been asked before in varying degrees, but I feel it has not been answered in a concise way and so I ask it again.

I want to run a script in Python. Let's say it's this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
        s = f.read()
    print s
```

Which gets a file location, reads it, then prints its contents. Not so complicated.

Okay, so how do I run this in C#?

This is what I have now:

```
    private void run_cmd(string cmd, string args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = cmd;
        start.Arguments = args;
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.Write(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I pass the `code.py` location as `cmd` and the `filename` location as `args` it doesn't work. I was told I should pass `python.exe` as the `cmd`, and then `code.py filename` as the `args`.

I have been looking for a while now and can only find people suggesting to use IronPython or such. But there must be a way to call a Python script from C#.

Some clarification:

I need to run it from C#, I need to capture the output, and I can't use IronPython or anything else. Whatever hack you have will be fine.

P.S.: The actual Python code I'm running is much more complex than this, and it returns output which I need in C#, and the C# code will be constantly calling the Python code.

Pretend this is my code:

```
    private void get_vals()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            run_cmd("code.py", i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the C# code have to call the Python script or is it OK if (like you stated at the end) you just call the python interpreter which then runs the script?

Comment: Are you allowed to use IronPython?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis its okay, i just need to be able to run it through c# and catch the output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75983934/5967360

Answer (score 176, accepted):

The reason it isn't working is because you have `UseShellExecute = false`.

If you don't use the shell, you will have to supply the complete path to the python executable as `FileName`, and build the `Arguments` string to supply both your script and the file you want to read.

Also note, that you can't `RedirectStandardOutput` unless `UseShellExecute = false`.

I'm not quite sure how the argument string should be formatted for python, but you will need something like this:

```
private void run_cmd(string cmd, string args)
{
     ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
     start.FileName = "my/full/path/to/python.exe";
     start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", cmd, args);
     start.UseShellExecute = false;
     start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
     using(Process process = Process.Start(start))
     {
         using(StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
         {
             string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
             Console.Write(result);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: i want to be able to take the output to my program to be used later. so i need to have shellexecute as false. you are saying if i pass `c:\python26\python.exe` as `cmd` and then `c:\temp\code.py c:\temp\testfile.txt` as `args` it should work?

Comment: I updated with a quick example, I ran into the same issue when I did something similar with node

Comment: okay, it works for me now. the problem is that you need to format the strings very carefully. any paths need `"PATH"` even if there are no spaces... strange...

Comment: Mine works without providing the full path. I am setting `UseShellExecute` to `false` and `RedirectStandardOutput` to `true`.

Comment: Works without providing the path if the Python installer was told to add the Python directory to the environment variable PATH (system or user specific).

Comment: why my console go away immediately? I have tried to use process.WaitForExit() but it also goes immediately. I cannot capture any output from my python script.

Comment: Add a line of `Console.ReadLine();` after `Console.Write(result);` and you should be able to see the result because it is waiting for any key press to exit.

Comment: FYI I could not get the output because my file name has special characters, be careful!

Comment: @MasterMorality , the python scripts executes fine , but if there is some module dependency in the python, how can we resolve that?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi Because you are providing the path of the Python .exe file, you have control over which Python executable to run. You can use Pip to install the dependencies for that python environment in a separate command line terminal.

Comment: Not sure how it will work on Godaddy windows shared hosting, anyone tried before?

Answer (score 75):

If you're willing to use IronPython, you can execute scripts directly in C#:

```
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;

private static void doPython()
{
    ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    engine.ExecuteFile(@"test.py");
}
```

[Get IronPython here.](http://ironpython.net/)

Comment: explain this to me, can i do this without having to download anything? c# comes ready with this plugin? also - can i run external scripts with this?

Comment: You would have to install IronPython, which is open source.  I have updated the answer.

Comment: note that IronPython and Python are not exactly the same thing. Just for the record...

Comment: 1. Is IronPython compatible with .NET 3.5? 2. Can I pass any parameters while executing python file (those parameters may be instances of my own classes)? The most useful thing would be if I could run just one function from python script with known name and arguments.

Comment: IronPython doesn't seem to support the same set of language features as Python 3.6.x does. Therefore IronPython is only an option if you don't use any of those language features. It's definitely worth a try, though.

Comment: can we run python 3.6 with ironpython 2.7 version. I tried but its not import any python libraries. I am getting `unexpected token from` please help

Comment: No, IronPython is only compatible with Python 2.7. IronPython3 is in the works.

Comment: @RonKlein, they are not the same, and if you are trying to use a library such as scikit-learn (for ML purposes), it won't work for you either

Comment: In case either IronPython.Hosting or Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting cannot be found, you need to add References to your IronPythonInstallPath\Microsoft.Scripting.dll and IronPythonInstallPath\IronPython.dll

Answer (score 40):

#### Execute Python script from C

Create a C# project and write the following code.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            run_cmd();
        }

        private void run_cmd()
        {

            string fileName = @"C:\sample_script.py";

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Python27\python.exe", fileName)
            {
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true
            };
            p.Start();

            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();

            Console.WriteLine(output);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

#### Python sample_script

```
print "Python C# Test"
```

You will see the ***'Python C# Test'*** in the console of C#.

Comment: I have a python script file in a Windows folder like `C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2019`. Because of the space in the folder path, it is treated as args' delimiter, so I got the `fileName` cannot be found. Is there a way to escape the space?

Comment: I have a script that leverages pip packages. Will this still work? Do I just put the packages in the same folder as the python.exe?

Comment: Maybe pip packages will be in venv\Lib\site-packages where the .py script is, worth a try

Answer (score 20):

I ran into the same problem and Master Morality's answer didn't do it for me.  The following, which is based on the previous answer, worked:

```
private void run_cmd(string cmd, string args)
{
 ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
 start.FileName = cmd;//cmd is full path to python.exe
 start.Arguments = args;//args is path to .py file and any cmd line args
 start.UseShellExecute = false;
 start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
 using(Process process = Process.Start(start))
 {
     using(StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
     {
         string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
         Console.Write(result);
     }
 }
}
```

As an example, cmd would be `@C:/Python26/python.exe` and args would be `C://Python26//test.py 100` if you wanted to execute test.py with cmd line argument 100.  Note that the path the .py file does not have the @ symbol.

Comment: Can someone comment on why this is -1. What's wrong with it.

Comment: It is exactly the same as the answer above just your assigning FileName from a parameter instead. But at the end `start` has the same values

Answer (score 5):

Actually its pretty easy to make integration between Csharp (VS) and Python with IronPython. It's not that much complex... As Chris Dunaway already said in answer section I started to build this inegration for my own project. N its pretty simple. 
Just follow these steps N you will get your results.

step 1 : Open VS and create new empty ConsoleApp project.

step 2 : Go to tools --> NuGet Package Manager --> Package Manager Console.

step 3 : After this open this link in your browser and copy the NuGet Command. 
         Link: https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPython/2.7.9

step 4 : After opening the above link copy the PM>Install-Package IronPython -Version 2.7.9 
         command and paste it in NuGet Console in VS.
         It will install the supportive packages.

step 5 : This is my code that I have used to run a .py file stored in my Python.exe 
         directory.

```
using IronPython.Hosting;//for DLHE
using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;//provides scripting abilities comparable to batch files
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
class Hi
{
private static void Main(string []args)
{
Process process = new Process(); //to make a process call
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine(); //For Engine to initiate the script
engine.ExecuteFile(@"C:\Users\daulmalik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\p1.py");//Path of my .py file that I would like to see running in console after running my .cs file from VS.//process.StandardInput.Flush();
process.StandardInput.Close();//to close
process.WaitForExit();//to hold the process i.e. cmd screen as output
}
}
```

step 6 : save and execute the code

Comment: As a developer I don't pick a solution because it's "easy" to implement. I pick one that does the job. IronPython is ported only to python 2.7 and work on python 3 is on course for a couple of years now, without end in sight. Hope your python code is in the right version.

Comment: as of 27 april 2020: https://github.com/IronLanguages/ironpython2/releases/tag/ipy-2.7.10, but still not python 3.

Answer (score 3):

Set WorkingDirectory or specify the full path of the python script in the Argument

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
start.FileName = "C:\\Python27\\python.exe";
//start.WorkingDirectory = @"D:\script";
start.Arguments = string.Format("D:\\script\\test.py -a {0} -b {1} ", "some param", "some other param");
start.UseShellExecute = false;
start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
    {
        string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.Write(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and used answers on here to solve it using a process. I had conflicts between my .NET and IronPython so wasn't successful there. This works well with my python 3.10.

```
public void Run_cmd2(string exe, string args, string output )
{
    var outputStream = new StreamWriter(output);

    // create a process with the name provided by the 'exe' variable 
    Process cmd = new Process();
    cmd.StartInfo.FileName = exe;

    //define you preference on the window and input/output 
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    cmd.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

    // write the output to file created 
    cmd.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((sender, e) =>
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
        {
            outputStream.WriteLine(e.Data);
        }
    });
    cmd.Start();

    // write to the console you opened. In this case for example the python console 
    cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(args);

    //Read the output and close everything. make sure you wait till the end of the process 
    cmd.BeginOutputReadLine();
    cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
    cmd.StandardInput.Close();
    cmd.WaitForExit();

    //close the process. writing to debug helps when coding
    outputStream.Close();
    //Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()); 
    cmd.Close();
    Debug.WriteLine("\n\n Process done!");
    //Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Example call:

```
string pythonEngine = "C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\envs\\compVision\\python.exe";

string pythonArguements =  "import os ; os.chdir('C:\\YourPath\\excelWorkbooks') ; import testSearch ; testSearch.performAdd(2, 3)";
 
// here a function in testSearch.py is called. To run the .py directly do this:

string pythonArguements =  "import os ; os.chdir('C:\\YourPath\\excelWorkbooks') ; import testSearch ; testSearch.py";

outFile  = "C:\\YourPath\\output.txt";

_yourModuleName.Run_cmd2(pythonEngine, pythonArguements, outFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having problems with `stdin/stout` - when payload size exceeds several kilobytes it hangs. I need to call Python functions not only with some short arguments, but with a custom payload that could be big.

A while ago, I wrote a virtual actor library that allows to distribute task on different machines via Redis. To call Python code, I added functionality to listen for messages from Python, process them and return results back to .NET. 
[Here is a brief description of how it works](https://github.com/buybackoff/Ractor/wiki/Calling-custom-Python-code-from-.NET).

It works on a single machine as well, but requires a Redis instance. Redis adds some reliability guarantees - payload is stored until a worked acknowledges completion. If a worked dies, the payload is returned to a job queue and then is reprocessed by another worker.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use in-out files? instead of having the pipes handle all of that work.

Comment: @InbarRose I already had the system for .NET, so adding Python processing was very easy and I still have distribution and reliability - e.g. I could post payload from a Windows machine and process it from a Linux machine - files wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: @InbarRose And when payload is really big, I could pass a filename on the same machine or S3 reference on AWS, etc...

Answer (score 0):

had same issure and this worked for me:

```
using IronPython.Hosting;

  var engine = Python.CreateEngine();

  engine.ExecuteFile("") //put the directory of the program in the quote marks
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get my script to recognise imported modules using any of the above methods.

However, all I need to do is run the a script and consume its output.

It is enough for me to execute a Powershell script from my .Net code, and consume the result from Standard Output.

```
void ExecuteScript(string pathToScript, string arg)
{
  var scriptArguments = $"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File \"{pathToScript}\" \"{arg}\";
  var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell.exe", scriptArguments);
  processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

  using var process = new Process();
  process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
  process.Start();
  string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

  Console.WriteLine(output); 
}

ExecuteScript("runMyScript.ps1","hello world");
```

And the Powershell script just contains the line that you would use to run it from the prompt:

```
C:/path/to/python.exe c:/dev/pythonStuff/myScript.py $args[0]
```