# Checking if python package is already installed C#

Tags: c#, python

No code with this question because I've got no idea how to do this.  Basically would like to check if a python package has already been installed using C#.  The input is the url for the package ex: https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/n/numpy/numpy-1.7.1.win32-py2.7.exe.  The program should check if the package has been installed already.  Code, methods of doing this, anything is very appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Quick thought. Could you run (from C#, not sure myself how to do it) `python -c "import numpy" and check it's exit code?

Comment: @user3267581 That is a pretty cool idea. Just keep in mind that the command would return a failure exit code if python wasn't installed too.

Comment: Not a bad idea, will try this and let you know if I figure it out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

What operating system you are running? 
If its in Linux, you can call a shellscript that will execute a Python file. Within the file you can have a import statement that will import the package..

Comment: Check this link..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/run-a-python-script-from-c-sharp