# C# Python-based plugin system

Tags: c#, python, plugins

I am sorry I have no sample code or anything, I just need some information on how could I do this. I am developing a c# application that uses addons/plugins etc. I want thos addons/plugins to be Python scripts. How could I possibly achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [run a python script from c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/run-a-python-script-from-c-sharp)

Comment: That's not what I want, that code is executing the python script, I want to use python script as a plugin for my c# application.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/). It's essentially Python for .NET (assuming you're using .NET rather than Mono, although that may work too).

Comment: The main application is developed in c#, only small part of it is developed in Python, and that part is a plugin. Every script will be individual plugin.

Comment: @TheNeosrb have you considered IronPython?

Comment: Yes, I know how to execute python script in my c# application, the thing I don't know is how to reference all scripts from a folder? I don't know if I wrote that right. I have a folder where all scripts/plugins are stored and my application needs to lad them on launch.

Comment: @TheNeosrb: "I don't know is how to reference all scripts from a folder?" sounds like a C# programming question -- and perhaps the one you should be asking (or looking up in the C# documentation).