# How do I call a python script from a network drive using c#

Tags: c#, python, python-2.7

I'm calling a python script from a C# tool. I based my code on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-c). I use ProcessStartInfo to start python and pass a .py file and some argument to it. The code runs fine when the .py, CreateAssessorMap.py, file is on the c drive but not when it is on a mapped network drive. No error is thrown but no python code is executed as far as I can see. If I manually do the same operation from the command line it runs fine.

The code below the first procStartInfo.Arguments will fail as CreateAssessorMap.py is on a network drive. The commented out line below it would work as the script is on the C drive.

```
    private void btnPrint_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            procStartInfo.FileName = "python"; 
            procStartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", @"D:\Map_Generate_Scripts\CreateAssessorMap.py", this.txtSheet.Text, txtDestinationFolder.Text);
            //procStartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1} {2} ",  @"C:\Projects\Map_Generate_Scripts\CreateAssessorMap.py", this.txtSheet.Text, txtDestinationFolder.Text);
            procStartInfo.UserName = null;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            // Do not create the black window.
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

            // Now you create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo, and start it.
            using (Process process = Process.Start(procStartInfo))
            {
                using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    Console.Write(result);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ecpt)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ecpt.Message);
        }
        this.Parent.Hide();
    }
```

**Edit**
I added some error handling and the python code is failing with the message that the .py file cannot be found.

`python: can't open file 'D:\Map_Generate_Scripts\CreateAssessorMapCreateAssessorMap.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

I know it exists since I can run the file from the command line with the same arguments. So it seems that when I run from C# the python process can't find the d drive.

Comment: @DavidLee I don't think so. I can call a script from c#, just not when the script is on a network drive which as far as I can tell that question doesn't answer.

Comment: Ahh its on the network, did you try using the actual network path instead of the mapped drive letter?

Comment: @DavidLee yes good idea. it works if I use the full path.

Comment: Yes it works if I use the full path. Thank you. But I still need to figure out how to use mapped network drives. The network folks are always moving servers around.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that when it runs from a network drive it takes longer and your program does not wait for Python script's  completion. I suggest adding proces.Wait() before reading the output stream.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the python script produces output files. The files are not created when run from the network.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, the solution for Dowlers was to use the full path instead of the mapped network drive.

Change

```
@"D:\Map_Generate_Scripts\CreateAssessorMap.py"
```

To

```
@"\\[network path]\Map_Generate_Scripts\CreateAssessorMap.py"
```