# Windows IOT Python/UWP interaction on Raspberry pi

Tags: python, uwp, raspberry-pi, windowsiot

I am setting up a Raspberry PI 3 to work with a distance sensor and display to a UWP app. Specifically this model: https://www.tindie.com/products/upgradeindustries/hc-sr05--hy-srf05-precision-ultrasonic-sensor/.

I am looking for a way to run the distance calculation/GPIO in the background in Python, and then display the distance to a UWP app. Does anyone know if this is possible, or could point me in the right direction? Currently the UWP app I have is working, however it does seem unreliable.

Thanks!

Comment: I see two options here. You could integrate your UWP app and your python script with a Realtime database, and have your UWP read the values that your python script sends to it. Firebase offers a great realtime database. Otherwise, you could use a library like IronPython to integrate with .NET and use the .NET class libraries within the script. For the IronPython approach, I'm not exactly sure how seamless the integration would be.

Comment: I like the option of using a Realtime database, however I need this to work offline..(I know, not very IOT). Do you have any suggestions for offline realtime database?

Comment: Without internet, your only option would be IronPython. Here's a link with an example of how to read values returned from a Python script in c#. It details how to do it with native C# code, or the fully managed IronPython library (I recommend IronPython because it can catch and return exceptions in your python script): https://medium.com/@dpursanov/running-python-script-from-c-and-working-with-the-results-843e68d230e5

Comment: Maybe you can create a Python background service and consume it in UWP app. You can start with [AppServiceBlinky](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/appserviceblinky) and [Python Blinky app](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/helloblinkybackgroundpython) samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to write a driver for your ultrasonic in Python, see https://github.com/great-coder/RP_Drivers_Python/blob/master/Ultrasonic.py

Then read this [How do I run a Python script from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-c)
to call the python script periodically from UWP.
You can write the calculated distance inside of fun1 function in python into a file, then read the file inside the UWP app and update the value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know where the location of Python would be in Windows 10 iot core? Just trying to fill out all the variables.

Comment: @Parakoopa You can write a python program and deploy it into your windows iot (See: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/helloworldpython), then run your uwp and use python scripts without problem.

Comment: If you have problem to call your deployed python script on windows iot, you can use SQLite to sync your python with your uwp app.

Comment: [SQLite for python](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/)   |   [SQLite for UWP](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/windows10_development/windows10_development_sqlite_database.htm)