# Import librairy like JSON or XML for python, with IronPython on C# App

Tags: c#, python, xml, wpf, ironpython

I am trying to execute a Python Script on a C# Application. So I choose Iron Python, I have managed to execute basic code.

But while  using libraries like xml or json. I cannot import and use them. I've tried a lot,but nothing works out.

The main thing which I tried was to copy the xml librairy in my C# project folder, and then import it using the following code:

```
import clr
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("..\\ElementTree.py")
import ElementTree as ET
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("..json\\__init__.py")
import json
```

But i get this error :

```
System.BadImageFormatException: 'The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131018)'
```

Can someone provide me a with a good solution?

If you need more details, please comment the question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those methods load *.NET assemblies* not Python scripts

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You can just execute files for simple stuff. Like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-c  Somewhere... I think I have some code uses ironython for dynamic processing.

Comment: I need to execute python code in c# and this python code uses XML and JSON. Isnt IronPython a good solution to do this? Is there other better solution? Sorry to be so late on the response, i was working on somthing else and forgot this post.