# Run And Interact With Python Application from C# Script

Tags: c#, python, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use Unity C# (don't worry, easy to port to normal C# but I don't currently have a program that lets me do so) to run a python application using the following code, which basically just starts a python program and reads and writes some input and output:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
 using System.Text;

public class PythonSetup : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        SetupPython ();
    }

    void SetupPython() {
        string fileName = @"C:\sample_script.py";

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(pythonExe, "YOUR PYTHON3 PATH")
        {
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        p.Start();

        UnityEngine.Debug.Log (p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd ());
        p.StandardInput.WriteLine ("\n hi \n");
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());

        p.WaitForExit();
    }
}
```

The python application, located at C:/sample_script.py, is:

```
print("Input here:")
i = input()
print(i)
```

The C# program gives me the error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Standard input has not been redirected System.Diagnostics.Process.get_StandardInput () (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Diagnostics.Process:get_StandardInput ()
```

Thanks for the help ahead of time!

To put into normal C# project, just replace UnityEngine.Debug.Log with Console.WriteLine and replace Start() with Main().

Comment: I don't know C#, but it is possible that the first newline in  `p.StandardInput.WriteLine ("\n hi \n");` is interpreted as end-of-line for python's `input()` so it could be waiting for another input which never comes.  Try it without the newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your process so it knows to redirect input from the Standard Input stream and to your target application. Read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardinput?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Pretty much just amounts to including another property initialiser in your [ProcessStartInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
    p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(pythonExe, "YOUR PYTHON3 PATH")
    {
        //You need to set this property to true if you intend to write to StandardInput.
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };
```

Comment: Yeah it gets rid of that error, but now when I run it it gets stuck waiting for something; I'm not sure what's going on. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: SO already has a few pretty helpful questions on what your trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-c

You are replacing "YOUR PYTHON3 PATH" with your python script right?

Comment: No I'm replacing it with the path of the python.exe application. I've seen that post but my trouble comes when I try and input to the python application; that post only gets the application's output. Also, if you know any better way for me to communicate with a python file, please tell me

Comment: Well I'm not entirely sure what the problem is but the process has a bunch of events you can subscribe to, you could try using them to capture your output instead of `StandardOutput.ReadToEnd`. Check out what this guy is doing: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CaptureProcessOutput.aspx


At the very least you can capture errors that might be occuring when you are writing your input. Best of luck!