# Using phyton.exe in .net c# controller:

Tags: c#, .net

could not load file or assembly 'python.runtime' or one of its dependencies ,an attempt was made to load a program with an in correct format

im am facing same problem, My error was not resolved using phyton 3.5 , calling the phyton.exe path to execute phyton file in .net c# controller ,facing error only after publishing in to the server ,it working fine in my system

below was my code

```
if (Result.Success)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    startInfo.FileName = "C:/Program Files/Python 3.5/python.exe";
    startInfo.Arguments = "C:/PythonScripts/Test.py";
    // startInfo.Arguments = HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/PythonScripts/Test.py").ToString();

    startInfo.Verb = "runas";
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    process.StartInfo = startInfo;
    bool t = process.Start();

    StreamReader myStreamReader = process.StandardError;
    string error = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

    StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput;
    string output = reader.ReadToEnd();

    process.WaitForExit();
    process.Close();

    if (!error.Equals(""))
    {
        Result.Success = false;
        Result.Exception = true;
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rkM6T.png)

Comment: Please show some code. Are you using IronPython? https://medium.com/emoney-engineering/running-python-script-from-c-and-working-with-the-results-843e68d230e5

Comment: this was my code,Iam not using iron phyton :

Comment: Remove the line: `startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;` ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so much info about what you are using, but sometimes, the `badformatexception` is caused because your project configuration is not compatible with the dll it's complaining about, change it to x86 or to x64.