# Is there any way to create GUI in c# through python script?

Tags: c#, python-3.x, user-interface

I have coded a project in python and I want to make GUI for it. I am all new to GUI and don't have confidence in it.so it will be very time consuming for me to make GUI in python.

My colleagues have knowledge of c# and also they have experience of making GUI in it.so I want to ask is there any way that I can use such that my python script becomes compatible with c# for GUI designing?

I tried to make a GUI in python using Tkinter. but as I am new in this it will take a lot of time for me to acquire knowledge of it.and this project needs to be done soon

Comment: You essentially need to call a python script from C# and evaluate it's output. I do not consider this a very elegant approach, but it could work with either Process.Start(..) or IronPython (https://documentation.help/IronPython/getting_started.html). Ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-c and others