# IronPython "Invalid syntax"

Tags: python, ironpython

First time using IronPython trying to run a lib called emsndis, but I get "Invalid" syntax" while imporing the lib. It is located in the root folder of my project but I also have copy local set to true so it is also located in my bin-folder of my .exe-file.

If it try importing the lib in a "real" python file running from a stand-alone .py-file in the command prompt, it works just fine, so I believe this is something fishy with the config of IronPython.

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ICollection<string> paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
paths.Add(@"C:\Python27\Lib\");
paths.Add(@"C:\Users\bjorn\Documents\emsn-dis\env\Lib\site-packages");
paths.Add(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Lib\");
engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);

py("import math");
py("import time");
py("import signal");
py("import sys");

py("from datetime import datetime");
py("from collections import namedtuple");
py("from bitstring import Bits");
py("from emsndis import EmsnDis");

py("print 5");
engine.Execute(sb.ToString());
```

I have never worked with Python, nor IronPython so perhaps you need more info, just let me know.

Comment: Hi! Have you solved this problem? I have the same.

Comment: Nope, not even close

Comment: Yesterday I tried the other version to run a python script by using the solution of Derek in this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-c. It seems to work well. IronPython has a lot problem with dependencies.