# How to execute python file with passing arguments using C#

Tags: python, c#

I'm trying to execute the detect.py file using C# by creating a new process and passing ProcessStartInfo

Here is my method

```
         Process p = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"C:\Users\malsa\anaconda3\python.exe",
                RedirectStandardInput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = false,
                UseShellExecute = false
            };
            p.StartInfo = info;
            p.Start();

            using (StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput)
            {
                if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(string.Format("cd {0}", @"C:\Users\malsa\Desktop\Yolo"));
                    sw.WriteLine(string.Format("detect.py --source {0}", ImagePath));
                }
            }

            p.WaitForExit();
```

For now the arguments should be passed to cmd, but since am setting the file to python.exe the arguments should be written in python.

[Running detect.py using cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sEff.png)

As shown in the image this how we can execute the detect.py by giving the --source ImgFile.jpg in cmd.
The problem is that how can I execute the detect.py in Python-Shell by giving arguments such as ImgFile.jpg so that I can write these arguments in C# ?

I have tried something such as

```
subprocess.call(['C:\Users\malsa\Desktop\Yolo\detect.py', 0])
```

but I couldn't get it work.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-c) solve your problem?

Comment: I have seen it but as you can see the arguments passed is only (integer) which is easy to do, but how can I pass an image file to the detect.py

Comment: @MohammedAlsabi send the image file as a pickle file?

Comment: It's not possible, since the detect.py expect a image file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont use arguments?:

```
 Process p = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = @"C:\Users\malsa\anaconda3\python.exe",
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = false,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                // here 3 args with name of program python with 2 args
                Arguments = string.Format("{0} --source {1} {2}", "detect.py", "0", "image.jpg")
            };
            p.StartInfo = info;
            p.Start();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, It's working successfully, I was writing the arguments using the StandardInput Stream but when I passed the arguments to the Argument Property it worked.

Comment: standardinput is used to create command below os python