# Can I use C# to trigger a python script

Tags: python, c#

I would like to know if it is possible to execute a python script from C#, not with IronPython though since I want to use numpy and matplotlib, but I don't care about interacting with the script, I just want to trigger it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I run a Python script from C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-c)

Comment: You can use [Python.Net](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) to execute python scripts from .net process

Comment: The stackoverflow solution might work but I don't know what module to use(using;). As for Python.Net, it seems promising but does it support matplotlib as well?

Comment: @Logothetis we're using this library in our WPF application for scientists. Matplotlib, seaborn,  tensorflow are working fine. It's just wrapper for native `python.dll`.