# How to have a subprogramm in another programming language

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a Unity game that gives data to a subprogram written in Python and this subprogram gives back an answer, that is then processed in the C# game.

I don't really know how to approach this.
Can I run python code from C# somehow or do I let two separate programs running, that exchange data somehow?

Both programs also need access to the same database.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11779143/how-do-i-run-a-python-script-from-c

Answer (score 0):

You can make a python server using flask or fastAPI and then access it from C#. I am not sure how to get that done with C#(I dont know C# :( ), but there must be some libraries to call servers. Also, you could save the database on the cloud such as mongoDB.