# Execute a string as code

Tags: c#, string, eval

I wonder if there is some method of executing a string, or convert it to a code, example: 
"Console.WriteLine (\" Hello \ ")";

Equivalent to 'eval' in JavaScript.

I've translated it from Translate Google.

[Translate Google](https://translate.google.com.br/#pt/en/Ol%C3%A1,%0A%0AGostaria%20de%20saber%20se%20h%C3%A1%20algum%20m%C3%A9todo%20de%20executar%20uma%20string,%20ou%20seja,%20converter%20ela%20para%20um%20c%C3%B3digo,%20exemplo%3a%0A%22Console.WriteLine%28%5C%22Eae%5C%22%29%22;%0A%0AUm%20equivalente%20ao%20%27eval%27%20do%20Javascript.)

Comment: Sidenote: there is a portuguese version of Stack Overflow: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I read the properties of a C# class dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629/how-can-i-read-the-properties-of-a-c-sharp-class-dynamically)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964790/using-c-sharp-as-my-dsl-is-this-possible-if-so-how in which case ChristopheD's answer (below) is best.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit more contrived then using `eval` in some languages, [but it is certainly possible to programmatically compile code](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304655).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tutorial on something very similar to this a few years ago - it is based on compiling though:

http://domscode.com/2011/02/16/new-tutorial-tdd-c-web-compiler/

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try cshell: http://cshell.net/

It has a repl-based and executes c# code.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but it seems what you're looking for is easily feasible using Roslyn ( .Net compiler service )
Take a look at [eval()-like for C# using Roslyn and ScriptCS](https://gist.github.com/akimboyko/5682951) and [Hosted Execution of smaller code snippets with Roslyn](http://blog.filipekberg.se/2011/12/08/hosted-execution-of-smaller-code-snippets-with-roslyn/)