# How to parse a char in windows application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to continuously get this calculator to show the inputs, such as `1 + 1 = 2`, I believe the code is correct, yet when I run into `+ - / *` it needs parsed. I do not have the closest ideas how to do this.

I have tried for quite some time, so I char.Parse and if so where?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    char c;
    double num1;
    double num2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void btn0_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 0;
    }
    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 1;
    }
    private void btn2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 2;
    }
    private void btn3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 3;
    }
    private void btn4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 4;
    }
    private void btn5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 5;
    }
    private void btn6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 6;
    }
    private void btn7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 7;
    }
    private void btn8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 8;
    }
    private void btn9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Text += 9;
    }
    private void btnDecimal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!txtBox.Text.Contains('.'))
            txtBox.Text += '.';
    }
    private void btnAddition_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c = '+';
        num1 = double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
        txtBox.Text = string.Empty; // txtBox.Text += c;
    }
    private void btnSubtraction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c = '-';
        num1 = double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
        txtBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    private void btnMultiplication_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c = '*';
        num1 = double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
        txtBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    private void btnDivision_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        c = '/';
        num1 = double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
        txtBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }
    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtBox.Clear();
    }
    private void btnEqual_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double result;
        num2 = double.Parse(txtBox.Text);
        switch (c)
        {
            case '+':
                result = num1 + num2;
                txtBox.Text = result.ToString(); // txtBox.Text += result.ToString();
                break;
            case '-':
                result = num1 - num2;
                txtBox.Text = result.ToString();
                break;
            case '/':
                if (num2 != 0)
                {
                    result = num1 / num2;
                    txtBox.Text = result.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    txtBox.Text = "You can't divide by zero... sign up for Math 100 please =)";
                }
                break;
            case '*':
                result = num1 * num2;
                txtBox.Text = result.ToString();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by "parse a char"? "parse" means to discover internal structure of a string - there is no structure in `"+"`, it's a single character, and you even know what it is.

Answer (score 2):

The logic in your code is entirely flawed.

You can do three things:

Firstly, you can scrap what you're doing and go with a library that does this for you.. such as [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/).

Or, you can scrap what you're doing and look up an algorithm that does this.. such as the [Shunting Yard algorithm.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)

Or, you can keep trying to refine what you have.. but it might be best to look up other ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this suites your needs but perhaps you could try something like this:

[Is there a string math evaluator in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/is-there-a-string-math-evaluator-in-net/392355#392355)

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your code, your problematic line of code is:

```
txtBox.Text = result.ToString(); // txtBox.Text += result.ToString();
```

You're setting the textbox's text to the result of your computation (a + b, a - b, a * b, or a / b) rather than the expression and result that you desire.

As a result, I think you're looking for something like

```
txtBox.Text = num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + result.ToString();
```