# Validate mathematical Equation

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to write regular expression which ensure that mathematical equation syntax is true I tried many times but I didn't get what I want.

I need your help to find a regular expression to handle the following cases:

```
op1 = op2 [+-*/%^] number or op3*
```

allow nesting brackets

```
op1 = (op2 [+-*/%^] ( op3 [+-*/%^] op4 ) ) [+-*/%^] op5 or number*
```

And also allow merge of both Expressions and allow spaces between operands and operations

Comment: If your regex engine does not support recursive regexes, you are out of luck. Validate them with a recursive descent algorithm. Maybe you get lucky by counting the parentheses and validating each term with a regex, but that's bound to miss some cornercases.

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/is-there-a-string-math-evaluator-in-net

Comment: .NET Regex engine allowes for recursivity through balancing groups.

Comment: @knittl: C# and .net in general support recursion and have a stack system.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte NO WAY!

Comment: @Gusdor: What does it mean?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte it means we are all glad you are here to tell us that .net operates with a stack. knittl was referring to the regex engine itself.

Comment: @Gusdor: Sorry, I was speaking about the regex engine itself.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte save it for the judge, scoundrel.

Comment: The takeaway here is though some so called regular expression libraries support that kind of matching, you'd be better off writing your own lexer and parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried do this with regular Expression but This was very hard, I make Equation validation using Stacks and it works fine

http://scriptasylum.com/tutorials/infix_postfix/algorithms/postfix-evaluation/

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through balancing groups, you can read the following article for a good demo and explanation of balancing groups.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21183/In-Depth-with-NET-RegEx-Balanced-Grouping