# Calculating a String in C#

Tags: c#, ncalc, dynamic-expresso

I want to calculate a string in C# using either NCalc or DynamicExpresso library, the problem is, when the calculation gets complex and the numbers are big, it returns the wrong result.
For example the code below returns -808182895 when it should return 3486784401

```
string value = "387420489*9";
value = new Interpreter().Eval(value).ToString();
```

Am i doing anything wrong?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to convert a string to a mathematical expression programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21750824/how-to-convert-a-string-to-a-mathematical-expression-programmatically)

Comment: Are you aware of how integer overflow happens?

Comment: @PawelFlajszer not really, since the user enters the numbers and the operations, i just provided a fixed expression so it can be easier to understand, it would be better to use something like NCalc or an external library, for me at least

Comment: @JoeSewell yes i am aware of that, hence why i asked for help

Comment: (long)387420489*(long)9 works.

Comment: Tested here: http://dynamic-expresso.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: If the string is parsed like C#, then `"387420489L*9L"` should ensure 64-bit signed integers, and `"387420489u*9u"` should ensure 32-bit _unsigned_ integers.

Comment: As other suggested I think that you must ensure that the variables are considered `long` or `decimal`. By default `9` is considered an integer and this will generate an overflow. You can write `387420489*(long)9` for example.

Comment: thanks @OguzOzgul your answer resolved my issue.

Comment: Thanks @DavideIcardi for the helpful answer

Comment: Can you mark it as solution if I add it as answer? comments are not answers actually.

Comment: Dear @phuclv the OP is having a specific problem with a third party component. He is not asking how to execute code statements dynamically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
(long)387420489 * (long)9
```

Dynamic Expresso has a web shell here where you can test the expressions;

http://dynamic-expresso.azurewebsites.net/

While testing on this web shell, I realized that;

```
 387420489L * 9 => Syntax error (at index 9). => does not accept type suffix
 (long)387420489 * 9 => -808182895 => overflow
 387420489 * (long)9 => 3486784401 => OK

 2147483647 + 1 => -2147483648 => int.MaxValue + 1 = int.MinValue (overflow)
 2147483648 + 1 => 2147483649 => When does not fit into Int32, interpreted as long
```

While most of these can be regarded as by design (considering how Dynamic Expresso evaluates the statement), there can still be further improvement.

Think of Javascript for example.

```
387420489*9 => 3486784401
```

The question is, is what we need

1. to execute the given arithmetic expression correctly, as we and the end-user expects,
2. to execute the given arithmetic expression the C# way?

The former, I think.