# How read function f(x) from textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Visual Basic, Visual Studio 2013

My question is how change this code to read any function that was wrote in textbox that the program did not pay conversion error.

```
Public Function f(Byval x As Double) As Double

        Return x * x + 2 * x    <- how read this function from textbox ?

   End Function
```

I try other one and did not work:

```
Public Function f(x) As Double

   f = TextBox1.Text

End Function
```

Comment: Which is it?  VBA or visual studio (i.e. .NET, which is not VBA).

Comment: Also -- if this is VB.NET (not VBA) --, looking more closely, I don't think this is possible.  I was going to suggest a delegate or lambda expression, but you can't provide that dynamically at runtime (as far as I know).

Comment: VBA using Visual Studio 2013 ; Windows Forms Application

Comment: You can use VBA in Visual Studio 2013?  That's news to me.  Is that a new feature in 2013?

Comment: @simoco seems to disagree.

Comment: `Return x * x + 2 * x` is definatly not a syntax of VBA

Comment: yes i can use vba in VS2013

Comment: error - "conversion to type 'Double' is not valid."

Comment: If your function name is "f" and you do this "f = TextBox1.Text" then it's the same as doing "Return TextBox1.Text". Your function is set to return a double, not a string.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7f62b87d-a35c-4074-a0f0-84a9dd7ff0a5/convert-string-to-formula maybe? Or http://ncalc.codeplex.com/

Comment: yes i know it, but is there any way to change it ? or to change TextBox.Text to double?

Comment: I think it really depends on how complex your function is - The quickest way would be to use soemthing like NCalc from what I see - http://ncalc.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=parameters&referringTitle=Home

Comment: So you are basically asking the program to read in a string and then break the string apart separating each piece into its correct data type and then perform the correct operations using the operators that were in the string?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a string math evaluator in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/is-there-a-string-math-evaluator-in-net)

Comment: @ja72 but it isn't work with function f(x):
`Dim sc As New MSScriptControl.ScriptControl()`<br />
`sc.Language = "VBScript"`
`Dim expression As String = "1 + 2 * 7"`
`Dim result As Double = sc.Eval(expression)`
`f = result`

Comment: @Pit998 - I do not understand your comment. What doesn't work with function `f(x)`?

Comment: What is "..program did not pay conversion error"?

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the value from the textbox, check to see if it is numeric, and then pass that value to the calculation.

```
' in some code somewhere, like maybe a click event
Dim value As Double = 0
If IsNumeric(Textbox1.Text) Then
    value = f(CDbl(Textbox1.Text))
End If
' Do something useful with value

' the rest of the code . . .

Public Function f(Byval x As Double) As Double
    Return x * x + 2 * x
End Function
```