# c# calculate multiple calculations from a string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, calculator

I'm making a calculator in c# (winforms) and I was wondering if there is a simple way to calculate a string with multiple calculations in it so for example: if you have the string `"124+241/2*5"` let the program calculate it and then get an int output.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/is-there-a-string-math-evaluator-in-net

Comment: Two things to think about: a) is 124+241/2*5 = (124+241)/2*5 or 124+(241/2*5)? b) either way, the result is not a whole number, what do you want the int to be? Round up? Round down? Error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you're basically looking for the C# equivalent of Javascript's `eval()` function.

I recommend the library [NCalc](https://github.com/ncalc/ncalc).

```
var result = new Expression("124+241/2*5").Evaluate()
```

Another calculating engine would be [Jace.NET](https://github.com/pieterderycke/Jace).

```
Dictionary<string, double> variables = new Dictionary<string, double>();
variables.Add("var1", 2.5);
variables.Add("var2", 3.4);

CalculationEngine engine = new CalculationEngine();
double result = engine.Calculate("var1*var2", variables);
```

There's also [Dynamic Expresso](https://github.com/davideicardi/DynamicExpresso).

```
var result = new Interpreter().Eval("124+241/2*5");
```

And you can use [Roslyn's](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples) ScriptingEngine to evaluate:

```
Roslyn.Scripting.Session session = roslynEngine.CreateSession();
session.Execute("124+241/2*5");
```

Comment: As of the time of writing, Jace.NET is unmaintained or at least dormant. You can use sonic (https://github.com/adletec/sonic), which is basically a maintained fork with performance improvements and bug fixes. Disclosure: I'm affiliated with the project.

Answer (score 1):

Well, "simple" is actually a pretty broad term... relative, I should say.  Anyways, there are a few libraries that have proved themselves to be very robust and are very popular for things such as this.

The first one is [NCALC](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) (http://ncalc.codeplex.com/):

```
// One of the examples.
Expression e = new Expression("2 + 3 * 5");
```

The second one is [Jace.NET](https://github.com/pieterderycke/Jace) (https://github.com/pieterderycke/Jace):

```
// One of the examples.
CalculationEngine engine = new CalculationEngine();
Func<Dictionary<string, double>, double> formula = engine.Build("var1+2/(3*otherVariable)");

Dictionary<string, double> variables = new Dictionary<string, double>();
variables.Add("var1", 2);
variables.Add("otherVariable", 4.2);

double result = formula(variables);
```

Both are fantastic, but from previous experience, I found that Jace.NET performs a bit better on more complex expressions (shouldn't be an issue for you here).

Answer (score 0):

There is not automatic way to do it, you'll either have to parse it manually or use some kind of functionality equivalent to JavaScript's `eval()`.

A nice alternative which doesn't require to use external libraries is `System.Data.DataTable.Compute`:

```
public double Evaluate(string expr)
{
    System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
    return Convert.ToDouble(table.Compute(expr, String.Empty));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CodeDom and Reflection give you the ability to dynamically build C# Code into a string, compile it, and run it all inside your program. This very powerful feature in .NET allows us to create the CodeDom calculator, a calculator that evaluates expressions (and even lines of C# code) inside a Windows Form.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/CodeDomCalculator08082005003253AM/CodeDomCalculator.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you need something like that: [Dynamic Expresso](https://github.com/davideicardi/DynamicExpresso)
You can add it to your program with NuGet