# Textbox containing calculation formula

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, calculator

I would like to create a textbox in a windows form using C# .Net, that will be able to handle simple calculations. For example, if the user writes in the textbox `=5*7` then when the textbox gets validated the `textbox.Text = 35`.

My question is how can I convert the string `"=5*7"` to `doubles` and symbols so as to make the calculations.

Comment: Take a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/is-there-a-string-math-evaluator-in-net).

Comment: @AlessandroD'Andria This is what I was looking for!

Comment: This may be a duplicate, but the answers on that post do not suggest CSharp.Scripting which is ,imo, a superior solution to any of them.

Answer (score 2):

use the CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting library here how to use it [wiki](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting library for this. It is [available from Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting)

```
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using System;

namespace ExpressionParser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Demonstrate evaluating C# code
            var result = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync("System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) > System.DateTime.Now").Result;
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString());

            //Demonstrate evaluating simple expressions
            var result2 = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(" 5 * 7").Result;
            Console.WriteLine(result2);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

nuget packages:

<package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Common" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting.Common" version="1.1.1" targetFramework="net461" />

Comment: I tried including the nuget package `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting 1.1.1`, but that does not include the namespace `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting` - so the example won't compile on my machine. As it seems, `CSharpScript` does not exist. Could you shed a light on this please?

Comment: @Matt see edit for the Nuget packages

Comment: You are right, thank you, I added the package to an empty console project and inserted your code. The key is to change the framework version to 4.6.1 before adding the nuget package - In my case the default setting for the framework was 4.5.2, which did not work (it was trying to import something but failed). After that change, it worked instantly.