# Is it possible to dynamically compile and execute C# code fragments within the context of a object/method?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction

This is an extension of this question: [Is it possible to dynamically compile and execute C# code fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments)

But is it possible to reference fields, properties and methods of a certain object? For example:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public int a, b;

    public int SomeMethod(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        return a + b + c;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        int c = 3;
        string code = "a = b = 2; int result = SomeMethod(a, b, c);";
        // Compile and execute code here
    }
}
```

The code obviously makes no sense in terms of functionality, but it's just an example.

Comment: I think you'll find what you want in here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/is-there-a-string-math-evaluator-in-net

Comment: No, he is asking for a math evaluator.

Comment: This: https://josephwoodward.co.uk/2016/12/in-memory-c-sharp-compilation-using-roslyn and this: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/compiling-c-sharp-code-into-memory-and-executing-it-with-roslyn will give you comprehensive starting point. Your keywords for search are "roslyn compile string". Roslyin is a C# compiler and it is available as a NuGet for consumption.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know a way, but you can call `string tmp = Path.GetTempFile()` to create a temp file and do a `code = "void Main(string[] args){int a = b = 2; int result = SomeMethod(a, b, c); File.WriteAllBytes(\"" + tmp + "\", BitConverter.GetBytes(result));"` to save the result. Then you can load it with `BitConverter.ToInt32(File.ReadAllBytes(tmp))`.

Comment: are you mad?   ......

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like Lambda Expression Serializers
[DynamicExpresso](https://github.com/davideicardi/DynamicExpresso)