# Make custom calculate method take any generic operator

Tags: c#, math

I have to calculate method which takes as parameters the *first* number, *second* number and the *operation*.

```
public static double Calculate(double firstNumber, double secondNumber, string operation)
{
    var result = default(double);
    switch (operation)
    {
        case "+":
            result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
            break;
        case "-":
            result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
            break;
        case "*":
            result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
            break;
        case "/":
            result = firstNumber / secondNumber;
            break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Right now i am using a switch. When the operation is a "+", i add the numbers.

**How could make the calculate method take any arithmetic operator as a parameter without having to add a specific case for it?**

My idea would by that in the end it looks like this:

```
public static string Calculate(double firstNumber, double secondNumber, string operation)
{
     return firstNumber operation secondNumber;
}
```

I know from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/is-there-a-string-math-evaluator-in-net) that there is a way, for example using

```
new DataTable().Compute("1 + 2 * 7", null)
```

this would require me to convert my numbers to string what i don't want.

Comment: i promise you i searched alot of links but i haven't found anything useable

Comment: That's because you have that specific requirement to have 2 number-type operands and the operator as string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's *extract model* in a form of *dictionary* for all these operators:

```
 private static Dictionary<string, Func<double, double, double>> s_Operators = new
   Dictionary<string, Func<double, double, double>>() {
     { "+", (x, y) => x + y },
     { "-", (x, y) => x - y },
     { "*", (x, y) => x * y },
     { "/", (x, y) => x / y },

     //TODO: Add new operations if you want, e.g.
     // { "^", (x, y) => Math.Pow(x, y) }, 
   };
```

Then you can easily implement `Calculate`:

```
public static double Calculate(double firstNumber, double secondNumber, string operation) 
{
  return s_Operators.TryGetValue(operation, out var func)
    ? func(firstNumber, secondNumber)
    : throw new ArgumentException($"Unknown {operation} operation", nameof(operation));
}
```

Please, note, that you have to `Dispose` `DataTable` instance, that's why computing with a help `DataTable` will be something like this:

```
private static double TableCompute(string formula) {
  using (DataTable table = new DataTable()) {
    return Convert.ToDouble(table.Compute(formula, null));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For `DataTable().Compute()` to work, there is no need to convert numbers to string,

```
using System;
using System.Data;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Addition -> " + Calculate(6, 3, "+").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Substraction -> " + Calculate(6, 3, "-").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Multiplication -> " + Calculate(6, 3, "*").ToString());
        Console.WriteLine("Division -> " + Calculate(6, 3, "/").ToString());
    }

    public static double Calculate(double firstNumber, double secondNumber, string operation)
    {       
        return Convert.ToDouble(new DataTable().Compute(firstNumber + operation + secondNumber, null));
    }
}
```

Output for input numbers 6 and  3

```
Addition -> 9
Substraction -> 3
Multiplication -> 18
Division -> 2
```