# How to add negative numbers to an array

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I have for example a line:

```
inputData = "-80 * 5-5"
```

There is the following code that splits positive numbers:

```
private static readonly char[] validOperators = { '/', '*', '+', '-' };

var numbersOfExpression = inputData
      .Split(validOperators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
      .Select(s => double.Parse(s)).ToList();
```

But it doesn't work with negative numbers.

I am looking for a solution without Regex as it creates additional complexity.

Comment: You can't use `string.Split` for this, for the reason you've observed. If you can't use regex, you're down to parsing through your string character-by-character

Comment: Forget Regex, you need a parser. That's a whole level more of complexity.

Comment: Save your self oodles of time trying to figure order of precedence and get your self a math library capable of parsing mathematical expressions

Comment: Use an available library like the `DataTable` class which [can do this out of the box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/is-there-a-string-math-evaluator-in-net/18796518#18796518): `Console.Write(new DataTable().Compute("-80 * 5-5", null));` --> -405

Comment: What happens with the following `-80 * 5-(-5)`?

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras brackets are not supported