# C# - Evaluate Excel Logical Formulas

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have an Application that need to evaluate Excel Logical Formulas and I use Excel DLL to do this, but DLL isn't it very efficient.

.NET Framework (C#) has any Class that can make this Job?

An sample

I Provide this

```
=IF(AND(10>=-5;10<0);(-3,8*10+335);IF(AND(10>=0;10<5);(1,4*10+335);IF(AND(10>=5;10<14,4);(-1,2766*10+348,38);IF(AND(10>=14,4;10<25);(-1,5094*10+351,74);IF(AND(10>=25;10<=45);(-1,4*10+349);0)))))
```

And get this

```
335,614
```

Thanks

Comment: This is best and awesome method CLICK [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437964/best-and-shortest-way-to-evaluate-mathematical-expressions/1438829#1438829)

Answer (score 11):

Yes, agreed, the [Excel.Application.Evaluate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223886(office.11).aspx) method can be slow. It usually suits my needs, but it's not lightening fast.

I think the best source for evaluating Excel formulas without the Excel object mode is:

- [Excel Formula Parsing, in C#](http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2007/03/excel_formula_p.html)

Some other related articles:

- [Invesitgation into Excel Syntax and a Formula Grammar](http://homepages.ecs.vuw.ac.nz/~elvis/db/Excel.shtml)
- [Runtime code generation to speed up
  spreadsheet computations](http://www.itu.dk/people/sestoft/corecalc/Iversen2006.pdf)
- [VectorExcel](http://www.nsl.com/papers/excel.htm)
- [Implementing an Excel-like formula engine](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/FormulaEngine.aspx)

Hope this helps...

Comment: The "Excel Formula Parsing, in C#" link is no longer live

Comment: Yep, the link of Excel Formula Parsing is broken.

Answer (score 5):

You could have a look at

[Implementing an Excel-like formula engine](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/FormulaEngine.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I am using [ActiveXls](http://www.activexls.com) and it's doing a great job. It's not a free component so you have to pay for it. I don't know if there are any good and free components out there, but I prefer to have support in case I need it :)

Answer (score 1):

We use [SpreadsheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) to do this - but it does a whole lot more than just evaluating formulas, so might be overkill for you.

It does seem to be fast, and provides a quite easy to use .NET API, too.

Answer (score 1):

I used bcParser.NET is a mathematical expression parser library for the .NET platform. this utility from bestcode organisation and easy to use to calculate all type of formula.
refer to this http://www.bestcode.com/html/math_parser_for_dot_net.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of math expression parsers out there, e.g. [lundin](http://www.lundin.info/mathparser.aspx), but I'm not sure they'll parse an excel expression for you.  Does it have to be excel?

Comment: Formula need to use Excel sintax