# how to convert excel formula to List or somestrongtype

Tags: c#, excel

There is a excel formula like :
`=A2/B2*C2+D2`

i expect to call somemethod like :

```
var formula = "=A2/B2*C2+D2";
var list = SomeMethod(formula);
```

and get List data like :

```
[0]:=
[1]:A2
[2]:/
[3]:B2
[4]:*
[5]:C2
[6]:+
[7]:D2
```

i have tried using regex for a while but i still have no idea.

Comment: i've updated the question. @SushantYelpale

Comment: So, these formulas Also Contains Excel Methods like `abs`, `sum`? Or only operators like `+`, `-`, `=`?

Comment: contatins `abs, sum` but it's difficult to one qeustion to answer,so i ask for `only operators like +, -, =` first.

Comment: For this purpose you will need `Parser` to parse it

Comment: @SushantYelpale first thanks your answer, and is there a opensource parser in C# or i have to code it myself?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2049355/c-sharp-evaluate-excel-logical-formulas

Comment: thanks @SushantYelpale , i found answer from your link [ewbi.develops: Excel Formula Parsing, in C#](https://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2007/03/excel_formula_p.html), can u answer below then i'll mark it answer.

Comment: Checkout my edit to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Excel formula Parser` for the case,
check out [here](https://github.com/spreadsheetlab/XLParser) or [here](https://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2007/03/excel_formula_p.html)

**EDIT**

For Simple use case like only few operators `+`, `-`, `/` you could use following version,

```
string[] splits = Regex.Split("=A2/B2*C2+D2", @"(?<=[+-=*/])");
```

Comment: I've used https://github.com/spreadsheetlab/XLParser to parse expressions.

Comment: FYI this only works because the `+-=` is actually matching any character from + to = which happens to include the minus character and the digits 0-9.  If the dash was properly escaped this would actually result in "=", "A2/", "B2*", "C2+", and "D2".  Also it's going to split on a bunch of other characters like a period, colon, semi-colon, and less than.