# Convert Expression from a Textbox to Math Expression in Code Behind

Tags: c#, math, equation, equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I need a fast runtime expression parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392022/i-need-a-fast-runtime-expression-parser)

How do I make it that when someone types in **x*y^z** in a textbox on my page to calculate that equation in the code behind and get the result?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/equation+c%23. Also, are you using ASP.NET? Silverlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved with this library http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21137/Inside-the-Mathematical-Expressions-Evaluator

my final code

```
Calculator Cal = new Calculator();
txt_LambdaNoot.Text = (Cal.Evaluate(txt_C.Text) / fo).ToString();
```

now when some one type 3*10^11 he will get 300000000000

Answer (score 5):

Answer from [operators as strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174664/operators-as-strings) by user https://stackoverflow.com/users/1670022/matt-crouch, using **built-in .NET functionality:**

"If all you need is simple arithmetic, do this.

```
    DataTable temp = new DataTable();
    Console.WriteLine(temp.Compute("15 / 3",string.Empty));
```

EDIT: a little more information. Check out the MSDN documentation for the Expression property of the System.Data.DataColumn class. The stuff on "Expression Syntax" outlines a list of commands you can use in addition to the arithmetic operators. (ex. IIF, LEN, etc.)."

EDIT 2: For convenience, you can put this into a little function like:

```
public string Eval(string expr)
{
    var temp = new System.Data.DataTable();
    string result = null;
    try
    {           
        result = $"{temp.Compute(expr, string.Empty)}"; 
    }
    catch (System.Data.EvaluateException ex)
    {
      if (ex.Message.ToLower().Contains("cannot find column"))
            throw new System.Data.SyntaxErrorException($"Syntax error: Invalid expression: '{expr}'."
                                           + " Variables as operands are not supported.");
      else
            throw;
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

So you can use it like:

```
Console.WriteLine(Eval("15 * (3 + 5) / (7 - 2)"));
```

giving the expected output:

> 24

**Note** that the error handler helps to handle exceptions caused by using variables which are not allowed here. Example: `Eval("a")` - Instead of returning `"Cannot find column [a]"`, which doesn't make much sense in this context (we're not using it in a database context) it is returning `"Syntax error: Invalid expression: 'a'. Variables as operands are not supported."`

Run it on [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Rf5spM)

Answer (score 5):

.NET does not have a built-in function for evaluating arbitrary strings. However, an open source .NET library named [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) does.

> NCalc is a mathematical expressions evaluator in .NET. NCalc can parse
>   any expression and evaluate the result, including static or dynamic
>   parameters and custom functions.

Comment: ' surprised your suggestion didn't readily percolate to the top.  I'd better do my part (+1) since I plug that approach in my own "manifesto"

Comment: **Note:**  **[NCalc](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=ncalc)** moved to Github: https://github.com/sheetsync/NCalc and will not be maintained any more. The (archive) link in the answer suggests to look into https://github.com/sebastienros/jint which is continued to be developed.

Answer (score 3):

There are two main approaches to this problem, each with some variations, as illustrated in the variety of answers.

- Option A: Find an existing mathematical expresssion evaluator
- Option B: Write your own parser and the logic to compute the result

Before going into some details about this, it is appropriate to stress that interpreting arbitrary mathematical expressions is **not a trivial task**, for any expression grammar other than "toy" grammars such as these that only accept one or two arithmetic operations and do not allow parenthesis etc.

Understanding that such task is deceivingly trivial, and acknowledging that, after all, interpreting arithmetic expressions of average complexity is a relatively recurrent need for various applications [hence one for which mature solutions should be available], it is probably wise to try and make do with "Option A".
 **I'd therefore second Jed's recommendation of a ready-make expression evaluator such as *NCalc***.

It may be useful however to **take the time and understand the various concepts and methods associated with parsing and interpreting arithmetic expressions**, as if one were going to whip-up one's own implementation.

The key concept is that of a [***formal grammar***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar).  The arithmetic expressions which the evaluator will accept must follow a set of rules such as the list of arithmetic operations allowed.  For example will the evaluator support, say, trigonometric functions, or if it does, will this also include say *atan2()*.  The rules also indicate what consitutes an operand, for example will it be allowed to input numerical values as big as say 45 digits. etc.  The point is that all these rules are formalized in a grammar.

Typically a grammar works on ***tokens*** which have previously been extracted from the raw input text.  Essentially at some time in the process, some logic needs to analyze the input string, *character by character*, and determine which sequences of characters go together.  For example in the `123 + 45 / 9.3` expression, the tokens are the integer value `123`, the `plus` operator, the integer value `45`, the `division` operator and finally the `9.3` real value.  The task of identifying the tokens and associating them with a token type is the job a [***lexer***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis).  Lexers can be build themselves on a grammar (a grammar which "tokens" are single characters, as opposed to the grammar for the arithmetic expression parser which tokens are short strings produced by the lexer.)

BTW, grammars are used to define many other things beyond arithmetic expressions.  Computer languages follow [rather sophiticated] grammars, but it is relatively common to introduce ***Domain Specific Languages*** aka DSLs in support of various features of computer applications.

For very simple grammars, one may be able to write the corresponding lexer and parser from scratch. But sooner than later the grammars may get complicated to the point that hand-writing these modules becomes fastidious, bug-prone and maybe more importantly difficult to read.  Hence the existence of [***Lexer and Parser Generators***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_generator) which are stand-alone programs that produce the code of lexers and parsers (in a particular programming language such as C, Java or C#) from a list of rules (expressed in a syntax particular to the generator, though many generators tend to use similar syntaxes, loosely base on [BNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)).

When using such a lexer/parser generator, work in done in multiple steps:
  - first one writes a definition of the grammar (in the generator-specific language/syntax)
  - one runs this grammar through the generator.
  - one often repeats the above two steps multiple times, because writing a grammar is an exacting exercise: the generator will complain of many possible ambiguities one may write into the grammar.
  - eventually the generator produces a source file (in the desired target language such as C# etc.)
  - this source is included in the overall project
  - other source files in the project may invoke the functions exposed in the source files produced by the generator and/or some logic corresponding to various patterns identified during parsing may readily be may imbedded in the generator produced code.
  - the project can then be build as usual, i.e. as if the parser and lexer had be hand-written.

And that's about it for a **20,000 feet high presentation of the process** of working with formal grammars and code generators.
A list of parser-generators (aka compiler-compilers) can be found at this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_generator#Several_compiler-compilers).  For simple work in C# I also want to mention [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/).  It may be very insightful to peruse these sites, to get a better feel for these concept, even without the intent of becoming a practitioner at this time.
As said, I wish to stress that **for this particular application, a ready-made arithmetic evaluator is likely the better approach**.  The main downside of these would be

- some limitations as to what the allowed expression syntax is (either the grammar allowed is too restrictive: you also need say stddev() or is too broad: you don't want your users to use trig functions.  With the more mature evaluators, there will be some form of configuration/extension feature which allows dealing with this problem.
- the learning curve of such a 3rd party module.  Hopefully many of them should be relatively "plug-and-play".

Answer (score 0):

What you need - if you want to do it yourself - is a **[Scanner (also known as Lexer)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) + [Parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser)** in the code behind which interprets the expression. Alternatively, you can find a 3rd party library which does the job and works similar as the JavaScript `eval(string)` function does.

Please take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser), it describes an **recursive descent parser**. The example is written in **C**, but you should be able to adapt it to **C#** easily once you got the idea described in the article.

It is less complicated than it sounds, especially if you have a limited amount of operators to support.

The advantage is that you keep full control on what expressions will be executed (to prevent malicious code injections by the end-user of your website).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement (or find a third-party source) an expression parser. This is *not* a trivial thing to do.