# Parsing a string C# (Possibly with Regex)

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing

I am trying to parse a line of code for a mathematical operation.

Such as: 4+18/(9-3)

I want the sections to be: 4, +, 18, /, (, 9, -, 3, and ).
So basically, all numbers, operators, and parenthesis.

If I use split with delimiters it removes the delimiter upon finding it. So if I use my operators as delimiters, well then they're removed.

I tried using Regex.split and it INCLUDES the operator, but not how I want it. It produces results like 4+, since it includes the 4 and the plus.

Here's what I've been trying:

```
        string convert = "4+8/(9-3)";

        string[] parts = Regex.Split(convert, @"(?<=[-+*/])");
```

Comment: You can use Regex to parse a string, but you cannot use regex to parse syntax. You would be better off using a math expression parser/evaluator.

Comment: But, to answer your question anyway, `([\d\.]+|[()e^/%x*+-])` should work. [(example)](https://regexr.com/3n63b)

Comment: If you plan to work with integers only, `Regex.Split(convert, @"(\D)");`. But it will not work as an end solution.

Comment: i am not sure but do u want numbers and signs separate ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392022/i-need-a-fast-runtime-expression-parser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment if you intend to use this to evaluate a math expression you should not use Regex as you cannot have any syntactic or semantic understanding of a string you're parsing.

If you're not intending to do that, this should work fine

```
([\d\.]+|[()e^/%x*+-])
```

[Regexr example](https://regexr.com/3n63b)

[Dotnetfiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/q7uf2Z)

Comment: @Aran-Fey You're correct, changed from `Regex.Split` to `Regex.Matches`

Comment: This added some extra "" empty string entries for me but I just created a quick loop to remove them. Not sure if I did something wrong to include them, but once the empty strings were removed which was easy enough the results so far from my testing have been desirable. Thanks.

Comment: @Birdman It's because of how `Regex.Split` works, if you check the Dotnetfiddle example I use `Regex.Matches` and loop through the matches it returns instead.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I guess the problem could be solved with the help of the following regex.

```
[-+*/\(\)]|\d+
```

Comment: Nope. This splits numbers into single digits.

Comment: Nope. Now it duplicates every character. And even if you change that capture group to a non-capturing group it still would split numbers into single digits. Please test your regex; this is getting silly.

Comment: "it still would split numbers into single digits" - how is that, @Aran?

Comment: Well, because it doesn't matter if you use `\d` or `\d+` in a lookbehind. After the regex passes the first digit, the lookbehind sees a digit and the number is split into two, `+` or not.

Comment: @Aran  I didnt think of lookbehind but now im actually not sure why op used it all

Comment: It shouldnt be a problem for it to work without lookbehind unless i am missing something else in the question

Comment: Now the result is just empty strings. I'm going to bed now and will check back tomorrow morning...