# Using regular expressions to calculate the number of variables in a mathematical function

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to regular expressions. I am working on a code in C# where I need to calculate the number of variables in a mathematical function. I store those variables in a list. Currently I am using the following regular expression:

```
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(inputFunction, "[a-zA-Z]"))
{
    variables.Add(match.Value);
}
```

The problem is that I don't want to add functions like Sin, Cos, Tan to the list. I only need to extract variables. For example if the user enters Sin(x), then I only need to add 'x' in variables list.

Comment: @l.b The post marked as duplicate seems to be totally unrelated to this question, as this is not about evaluating the expressions, but rather parse it and extract certain parts.

Comment: @jpw no you are wrong....

Comment: @EZI Please explain?

Comment: @jpw  See "LB"s answer....

Comment: @EZI I did. Ok, I read up a bit on what NCalc can do and it should be useful to do what the OP wants. Still don't think it's a duplicate question though.

Comment: @jpw so should we write the same answer here, just because the question is a little bit different.

Comment: @EZI Yes, there should possibly be a new answer here - not necessarily the same with minor adjustments. If the question is how to use regex to do a task, then maybe pointing to an answer requiring a third-party library isn't a perfect match. Maybe the OP can't use any external software and must do the parsing using regexes, who knows? I guess we'll just have to disagree.

Comment: @jwp, pure regex isn't enough. You need also a state machine. So the answer is: *you can't use regex* (at least there isn't a pure regex solution). But this other link can help OP more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593128/mathematical-expressions-parser

Comment: @EZI For the limited problem of extracting variables a regex might actually be enough, but sure, a proper parser would of course be better. Which might be what someone would have answered the OP if the question had still been open. :)

Comment: @jpw yes this someone would only repeat the previous answers :)

Comment: @EZI Fair enough. i can't cancel my reopen vote though, so maybe it will get reopened and closed again

Comment: @EZI Does NCAL have the feature to return the number of parameters though?  The closest I could see was that it would fire EvaluateParameter if the parameter was not already defined in the dictionary.