# Dynamic C# Formula Evaluation

Tags: c#, .net

Given a dynamic if statement in a String is there a method in .net to evaluate and return the correct result.

I.E.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String a = "if(\"Alex\" == \"Alex\"){return 1;}else{return 0;}";
        passThroughTest.Program.evalStatement(a);
    }
    public static void evalStatement(String statement)
    {

        //Evaluation of Statement

     }
```

This isn't perfect but in this case the end result would be a 1.  This seems 'stupid' from this point of view, but its for a more complex engine which needs to draw on similar syntax to evaluate.

Am I at a point where I need to write a parser of some sort and evaluate the statements...?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How complex are your statements going to be? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-sharp-code-fragments is a text book example of using the CodeDom

Comment: Thank you for that link.  Im going to dig into it a little more.  It should not be too complex; though it could get to a point where its nesting ifs or using switch statements.

Comment: This is best and awesome method CLICK [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437964/best-and-shortest-way-to-evaluate-mathematical-expressions/1438829#1438829)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- You can use [javascript.net](https://github.com/JavascriptNet/Javascript.Net)

  Sample code from their website:

  ```
  // Initialize a context
  using (JavascriptContext context = new JavascriptContext()) {

      // Setting external parameters for the context
      context.SetParameter("console", new SystemConsole());
      context.SetParameter("message", "Hello World !");
      context.SetParameter("number", 1);

      // Script
      string script = @"
          var i;
          for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
              console.Print(message + ' (' + i + ')');
          number += i;
      ";

      // Running the script
      context.Run(script);

      // Getting a parameter
      Console.WriteLine("number: " + context.GetParameter("number"));
  }
  ```
- Or use C# expression tree, see [Building Expression Evaluator with Expression Trees](http://www.aboutmycode.com/net-framework/building-expression-evaluator-with-expression-trees-in-csharp-table-of-contents/)

Comment: This method seems like it would use less overhead in the long run...  Im going to try it out and see how it works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What I think you are looking for is the CSharpCodeProvider : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx

This allows you to compile or evaluate C# code from a source and run it. It might not be as easy as evaluating a single "if" case, as when you compile C#, you are expected to have the whole syntax coming with it.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Im going to dig into that one and see how it compares to some of the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this:

```
var expression="(\"Alex\" == \"Alex\") ? 1:0"; 
var res = FlexRule.DynamicEvaluation.ExpressionEval.Default.Compute(null, expression);
```

For more details information of expression please have a look at 
http://wiki.flexrule.com/index.php?title=Expression