# Turn textbox text into string with code in it

Tags: c#, string, textbox

So I've made a function called `Something(string text)` that needs a `string`.
Now I have a button that onclick does `Something(textBox1.Text)`.

I want the `textBox.Text` to be able to be something like `"test " + (5+2).toString()`

Now the function will get `""test " + (5+2).toString()"` (for example) as input and it'll treat that like a big string.

What I want it to do is get `test 7` and not treat it like one big string.

How would I go about doing that?

Thanks in advance!
-Tim

EDIT:

This would be my function:

```
private void Something(string text)
{
    MessageBox.Show(text);
}
```

If I then do

```
Something(textBox1.Text);
```

When textBox1 looks like

```
__________________
| "hi " + "test" |
------------------
```

It will do make a MessageBox that says `"hi" + "test"` and not `hi test`.

Comment: So are you saying you basically want to allow someone to put any sort of coding in your text box? Is it limited to adding / subtracting numbers etc?

Comment: What do you mean by "one big string", could clarify your question?

Comment: The question is not clear.. could you please post your code?

Comment: So..you want that if the user writes in the textbox something like `5+2`,the function must return `7`?

Comment: If it is what I understand, I think you have your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10457244/579895)

Comment: @Pikoh Thanks, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to compile the string in your textbox and run the code before giving it to your `Something`-method.

Take a look at [Roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples#expr) to easily evaluate the expression from the textbox.

Then you'll get:

```
string result = await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<string>("\"test \" + (5+2).toString()");
Something(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you must try in this way. res contains the answer for the arithmetic operation.

```
 doSomething(string text)
    {            
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string[] operators = { "+", "*", "/", "-" };
        string[] data = text.Split(' ');
        for(int i=0; i< data.Length; i++)
        {
            if((operators.Any(data[i].Contains)))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(data[i].ToString());
                var res = dt.Compute(data[i],"");
            }
        }

    }
```