# Is there a way to evaluate formulas in a text box with C# in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, math, button, textbox

I am making a small game in ASPX with my friends.  We are working on a method that will break a string into commands and variables, and then do the math, but the code is slightly difficult and we would like to see if there is a short cut.

If I have a Button and a Textbox, is there a built in method which I can use to do math with that text box in order to find the value (e.g. the computer turns ((5-4)*(2+1) +(3/2))*2 into 9.

Comment: No, you will have to make one yourself or find a library that does it for you.

Comment: See the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234217/is-it-possible-to-compile-and-execute-new-code-at-runtime-in-net

Comment: I would do the evaluation on the client side using javascript. There's no point doing it on the server unless you have a requirement to do so. Check out the [math.js](http://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/parsing.html) library that does exactly that.

Comment: I need to as the math will be part of a multiplayer version of the card game krypto, and will function like Kahoot. If you think I should still use JavaScript or some other client side language, how would I get it to interact with the ASPX and the client data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a library called [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) to do it for you.

```
Expression e = new Expression("2 + 3 * 5");
Debug.Assert(17 == e.Evaluate());
```

A similar question was asked [Evaluating string "3*(4+2)" yield int 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18)