# how to add and subtract in C#?

Tags: c#, math

I am new to C# and I am trying to make a calculator. In Python(which I am more familiar with), You just `import math`and then write out what it is you want to do with math.

But with C#, this is my code:

```
using system;


namespace Calculator
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             divide(2,3);
        }
        public static void add(int num01, int num02)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The result is " + num01+num02);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static void multiply(int num01, int num02)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The result is " + num01 * num02);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static void divide(double num01, double num02)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The result is " + num01 / num02);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static void subtract(int num01, int num02)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The result is " + num01 - num02);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

And it firstly gives me 23 if I try to add, and throws a syntax error( Operator '-' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'int'.) if I try to subtract.

I'm only new to this language so I'm probably making some silly mistakes.

Comment: You're adding them as `string`.  You need to get the values as `int` first.

Comment: `"The result is " + num01 - num02` is like `("The result is " + num01) - num02`; the number gets concatenated to the string first, and then the subtraction happens. (It associates left-to-right.) Use parentheses to change that.

Comment: Console.WriteLine("The result is " + (num01+num02));``

Comment: Is there any language that computes `"Result = " + 4 -2"` as "Result = 2"?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234217/is-it-possible-to-compile-and-execute-new-code-at-runtime-in-net

Answer (score 6):

This mix-up comes from the confusion between two roles of `+`:

- When it is used in an expression with strings, it denotes *concatenation*
- When it is used in an expression with numeric types, it denotes *addition*

You can fix this problem by placing parentheses around your expressions.

However, a better approach is to use string formatting or [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) instead of concatenation, which lets you avoid this problem altogether:

```
Console.WriteLine("The result is {0}", num01 - num02); // Formatting
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine($"The result is {num01 - num02}"); // Interpolation
```

Answer (score 4):

convert your final calculation to a string like so.

```
Console.WriteLine("The result is " + (num01 - num02).ToString());
```

Or just wrap in parenthesis

```
Console.WriteLine("The result is " + (num01 - num02));
```

Comment: You don't have to use `.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

just put in order your operations with `()`.

```
namespace Calculator
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             divide(2, 3);
        }
        public static void add(int num01, int num02)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The result is " + (num01 + num02));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static void multiply(int num01, int num02)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The result is " + (num01 * num02));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static void divide(double num01, double num02)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The result is " + (num01 / num02));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public static void subtract(int num01, int num02)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The result is " + (num01 - num02));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Order of Operations is really important in strongly typed languages like Java and C#. Like many already answered you are first adding the string to the first number and then trying to subtract from the string.

This is what your code is doing:

```
1. "The result is " + num01 - num02
2. "The result is (value of num01)" - num02
3. Error when trying to subtract
```

By changing it to this

```
Console.WriteLine("The result is " + (num01 - num02));
```

Your code executes like this:

```
1. "The result is " + (num01 - num02)
2. "The result is " + (difference of num01 and num02)
3. "The result is (difference of num01 and num02)"
```

Hope this helps