# What's the best way to parse dynamic JSON data

Tags: c#, json, .net, formatting, string-parsing

Imagine a method accepting 2 string arguments:

```
public int Method(string expression, string variables) { ... }
```

`"expression"` is expected to be a math. expression (e.g. "1 + 2") that needs to be evaluated. And if there's something except for numbers & operators, I need to look up for that `variable` in `"variables"` string argument, to replace that variable with the number it represents. (There's no guarantee that the variable is defined in `"variables"`, but I believe it's not important here).

Input example:

```
Method("351 + x", "{ \"x\":69 }");
// Expected output: 420
```

Example of other valid `"variables"` values:

- { "x":123 }
- { "x":123, "y":420 }
- { }
- { "z":69 }
- { "abc": 777 }

**I wonder what's a good way to parse & retrieve data from a JSON (that may have a different structure each time (i.e. different number of properties & names)), to map it with the `variable` in `"expression"` string?**

Comment: How about mapping to a `Dictionary<string, object>` or similar?

Comment: @UweKeim yeah, that seems to be a good solution. Is there a way to do that w/o any 3rd party libraries/nuget packages? I was solving a problem on HackerRank & not sure I could use "Newtonsoft.Json" for example

Comment: I would not even _dare_ to do it on my own. Newtonsoft FTW!

Comment: Yeah makes sense... And probably there was an access to that library, but unfortunately I haven't checked that. Thanks for your help. Easy solution, haven't thought of that for some reason... You can post this as an answer, so I can accept it if you want :) Thanks again!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to compile and execute new code at runtime in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234217/is-it-possible-to-compile-and-execute-new-code-at-runtime-in-net)

Comment: @Charlieface I don't think it does :) It's kinda relevant to the topic, but not to the question I had. Thanks for linking anyway

Comment: OK misunderstood. What about this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65727513/json-deserialization-to-c-sharp-with-dynamic-keys

Comment: @Charlieface yeah, that's the one 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would go with [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and use a mapping to a `Dictionary<string, object>`:

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public int Method(string expression, string variables) 
{ 
    var varsDic = 
        JsonHelper.IsValidJson(variables)
            ? JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(variables);
            : new Dictionary<string, object>()

    // ...
}
```

[Example](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeDictionary.htm), [documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/t_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert.htm).

With `IsValidJson` being something like this:

```cs
public static class JsonHelper
{
    public static bool IsValidJson(string json)
    {
        return IsValidJson(json, out _);
    }

    public static bool IsValidJson(string json, out Exception parseError)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(json))
        {
            parseError = new Exception(Resources.JsonEmpty);
            return false;
        }

        json = json.Trim();
        if (json.StartsWith(@"{") && json.EndsWith(@"}") || //For object
            json.StartsWith(@"[") && json.EndsWith(@"]")) //For array
        {
            try
            {
                JToken.Parse(json);

                parseError = null;
                return true;
            }
            catch (JsonReaderException x)
            {
                parseError = x;
                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                parseError = x;
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            parseError = new Exception(Resources.JsonNoStartEnd);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

[See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977848/how-to-make-sure-that-string-is-valid-json-using-json-net).

Comment: Isn't better to wrap `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` in try/catch rather than parsing twice, once for checking and other for data?

Comment: @AlexeyRumyantsev Yes, that would probably be more performant, but on the other hand, maybe in a real-world-scenario it is negligible.