# How can I evaluate a math expression represented by a string?

Tags: c#, expression-evaluation

It's easy to implement a "Calculator" to parse a string (e.g., `2 ^ 3 / 2`) and compute the result of operations.  But, is there a library already capable of doing this?

Comment: Do you mean (2^3)/2 or 2^(3/2)?

Comment: it won't be that easy, as being a compiled language c# doesn't have an eval function (unlike perl for example)

Comment: Do you mean `2 to the power of 3 divided by 2` or `2 XOR 3 divided by 2` ?

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-expression-dynamically

Comment: I mean "2 to the power of 3 divided by 2", but "2 XOR 3 divided by 2" is nice also! Nevertheless it was only an instance example, just to make title looks good. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [dotMath](http://www.codeplex.com/dotMath) library does this.

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need some kind of math parser in order to do that. I've used [C# Expression Parser using RPN by DeepEddie](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/rpn_expressionparser.aspx) before, or you could make your own if the complexity of the expressions you use are of more limited scope.

Don't let it scare you, it is actually quite easy to make.

Comment: it's only "easy" for very simple cases

Comment: Most things tends to be easier when it is simpler.

Comment: i just mean that the apparent easiness of writing a calculator that parses an input string is deceptive. It's actually a non-trivial problem. If you don't believe me, try it.

Answer (score 1):

embed ironpython in your app, you can then ask it to evaluate arbitrarily complex strings

i think they even have a sample of the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Reverse Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). It's widely used in modern calculators

Comment: I don't see how this is helpful.  The OP is looking for an existing library and not looking to implement his own parser (and thus reinvent the wheel)

Comment: But knowing the name of thing you are looking for can be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the JScript library although its deprecated. Not saying you should, just that you could.

[Microsoft.JScript.Eval.JScriptEvaluate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5wwc36d.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this :

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.JScript;


  public class JScriptEvaluator
  {
        public   int EvalToInteger(string statement)
        {
              string s = EvalToString(statement);
              return int.Parse(s.ToString());
        }

        public   double EvalToDouble(string statement)
        {
              string s = EvalToString(statement);
              return double.Parse(s);
        }

        public   string EvalToString(string statement)
        {
            object o = "-1";
            try
            {
             o=  EvalToObject(statement);
            }
            catch { o = "-1"; }
              return o.ToString();
        }

        public   object EvalToObject(string statement)
        {
              return _evaluatorType.InvokeMember(
                                "Eval",
                                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                                null,
                                _evaluator,
                                new object[] { statement }
                          );
        }

        public JScriptEvaluator()
        {
              CodeDomProvider provider = new Microsoft.JScript.JScriptCodeProvider();

              CompilerParameters parameters;
              parameters = new CompilerParameters();
              parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;

              CompilerResults results;
              results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, _jscriptSource);

              Assembly assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
              _evaluatorType = assembly.GetType("Evaluator.Evaluator");

              _evaluator = Activator.CreateInstance(_evaluatorType);
        }

        private   object _evaluator = null;
        private   Type _evaluatorType = null;
        private   readonly string _jscriptSource =

              @"package Evaluator
              {
                 class Evaluator
                 {
                       public function Eval(expr : String) : String 
                       { 
                          return eval(expr); 
                       }
                 }
              }";
  }
```