# Realtime complination in C#

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, windows-phone-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a method that will evaluate a string and produce an integer (assuming the string is an equation) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384837/is-there-a-method-that-will-evaluate-a-string-and-produce-an-integer-assuming-th)

Hi all, i just wonder how to make a realtime complination in C#
For example: i have a string like this

```
string math = "1 + 2 + (4 - 6)";
```

And i want to complie it to get the result
How to do that? and is that the bad idea because i want to make a calculator in C#?

**Edited:**
The main question properly is that i want to do it in WP7, not exactly in C# windows lol, i tried all the solutions below but not at all is correct!

Comment: I always complinate in real time

Comment: http://forums.techarena.in/software-development/1109842.htm ?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-code-fragments

Comment: Several hints there, including a possible code that solves the problem : http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-csharp/31854/How-to-evaluate-a-math-expression-contained-in-a-string

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355062/is-there-a-string-math-evaluator-in-net, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607798/converting-string-expression-to-integer-value-using-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/c-evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437964/best-and-shortest-way-to-evaluate-mathematical-expressions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/826398/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-compile-and-execute-c-code-fragments

Answer (score 0):

> and is that the bad idea because i want to make a calculator in C#?

One problem with that is that your calculator language is probably supposed to be just a subset of C#. So using the C# compiler may be too flexible and allow arbitrary C#. Kind of like problems with SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

**Expresion Evalution** is  an application of [STACK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28data_structure%29) (Data Structure)

You can see these link If you want Sample projects

1. http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=397264
2. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/runtime_eval.aspx
3. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mgold/codedomcalculator08082005003253am/codedomcalculator.aspx