# Mapping variables from a string formula

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textarea where user can create a dynamic formulas using dropdown lists(for operators, variables etc) like this:

```
basic / workingDays * attendingDays
```

where values of `basic`, `workingDays`, `attendingDays` are saved in database. I want to map these variable from database during runtime. How can I do this.

Comment: check this out http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharplanguage/thread/f92d53b5-1bba-424a-8991-7e9e54787c23

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) is a very powerful framework that you could try.  They let you define dynamic parameters which sounds like exactly what you need.  You can do something like this:

```
var e = new Expression("basic / workingDays * attendingDays);

//Set up a custom delegate so NCalc will ask you for a parameter's value
//   when it first comes across a variable
e.EvaluateParameter += delegate(string name, ParameterArgs args)
{
   if (name == "basic")
       args.Result = GetBasicValueFromSomeWhere();
   else if (/* etc. */)
   {
       //....
   }

   //Or if the names match up you might be able to something like:
   args.Result = dataRow[name];
};

var result =  e.Evaluate();
```

There are also some related questions out there such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333737/c-evaluating-string-342-yield-int-18) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384837/is-there-a-method-that-will-evaluate-a-string-and-produce-an-integer-assuming-th) that give some other options.

Comment: This does exact what I needed but I can not use If and else block using NCalc.e.g. 
if(workingdays > 15)
   (basic+1000) / workingDays * attendingDays

Comment: NCalc does have a built-in if function.  The syntax is slightly different than it might be in C#.  You do something like: `if(someCondition, value when true, value when false)`

Comment: I am trying to do same but it is throwing exception (missing EOF at ',' at line 1:10)

Given condition is: var e = new Expression("if(10>11), 10, 12");

Comment: You have your parenthesis in the wrong place.  It should be `new Expression("if(10>11, 10, 12)");`.  In NCalc, `if` is a normal function that takes three parameters so you need to have the all three parts inside the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try to exploit `Expression` property of `DataColumn` in a `DataTable`.