# Indirect code execution/C#

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

#### Background

We currently have an excel-based system  for the creation of specifications for a sound and lighting rental company.

Part of this is a column in the excel sheet called 'autospec', which is made up of Excel formulas for individual stock items ( e.g., you specify a loudspeaker, and then the formulas in the `autospec` column calculate the cables you need and add them onto the specification automatically.

#### sample formula

10m microphone cable might have a formula like the following:

```
=IF([loudspeakers]>0,[loudspeakers]*2,0)+([mixing desk]*4)
```

We're now moving over to a proper database with a C# front end.

#### Question

What I would like is to be able to store the `autospec` formulas for each stock item in a table, and when the user specs an item the front end, the program should find the relevant formula, execute it, and change the spec quantity as appropriate.

Bottom line: I need to execute code contained within a string.

Am I going about this the wrong way?
Is there a better way?

Comment: I'd tend to write your rules in C#. You have a good programming language with a good IDE, why not use it?

Comment: Yeah that's what I intend to do, the Excel formula was just to illustrate what we USED to do. 8 years of pain have brought me to the point of hatred of Excel for anything other than simple number crunching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked a similar question once: [How can I evaluate a C# expression dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-expression-dynamically)

You could probably use that to evaluate those expressions. This not really a safe thing to do, unless you can guarantee nobody will be adding junk (read: evil code) to your database.

If you can break down the formulas into "families", such that each entry in your formula column is a member of a small (5-10) set of formulas with just different parameters, you could try something like this:

```
[ItemTable]<-[ItemFormulaParameters(param1, param2, param3)]->[FormulaTable(name)]
```

And have a factory method for instantiating the formula objects by name. Each such formula object has a "calculate(param1, param2, param3)" property...

Answer (score 0):

Either build you're own code interprenter or build a 'dynamic rule engine' that creates some binary representation of c# rules that can be executed by a 'rule engine' you'd have to write.