# string contain math expression

Tags: c#, .net, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I evaluate a C# expression dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-expression-dynamically)

If I have a string with a valid math expression like " (2 + 4)/2", how can
I evaluate it?

parser should calculate the result of the string (result 6)

thanks

Comment: isnt the result actually 3? ;)

Comment: What's missing that the result should be 6?

Comment: It's not a very good parse if it evaluates that to 6.

Comment: LOL u see i'm Really need the solution!! thanks i got my answer above "possible duplicate"