# c# convert string expression to a boolean expression

Tags: c#, parsing, expression-trees

Is it possible to convert a string expression into a boolean condition?

For example, I get the following string:

```
var b = "32 < 45 && 32 > 20"
```

I would like to create a `bool` expression out of this and invoke it. The string representation is also flexible (to make it more fun), so it allows `||, &&, ()`.

Comment: Also see [how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-sharp-expression-dynamically?lq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-sharp-expression-dynamically?lq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/), the .NET language kit. You could construct a simple grammar with Irony and then parse the string into executable command. There's a decent example of an arthmetic grammar in this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/YourFirstDSLPart2.aspx) and in the [Expression Grammar Sample](http://irony.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Expression%20Grammar%20sample&referringTitle=Home), its a pretty common request ;)

I definitely suggest using a proper compiler as opposed to Regex or a roll your own approach - it will be much more extensible if you ever want to add more rules.

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [Flee](https://github.com/mparlak/Flee) (Fast Lightweight Expression Evaluator) on CodePlex.

Comment: Man, what an incredible library! It worked perfectly for me. Thank you very much for your tip.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this library @Richard, this is exactly what I needed!!!

Answer (score 2):

If it follows all C# expression rules then compile it as dynamic code as per http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dynamiccode/dynamiccode.htm

Comment: How fast is that? I imagine it being quite slow

Comment: Not fast at all. Basically you invoke the C# compiler, which emits the IL of the expression, which is then wrapped in a method, then in a class, then in a dynamic assembly which is loaded into the current AppDomain, then you invoke the method through reflection to get the evaluation result. But it's a breeze to integrate, if it's just for a proof of concept or something...

Comment: Yes, I know how it works. I just wanted to point out that it would be a really slow way to do it

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with relatively simple mathematical expressions then a straightforward implementation of the [shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my library, [Proviant](https://github.com/Genfood/Proviant). It's a .NET Standard library using the [Shunting Yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) to evaluate boolean expressions. You could also implement your own grammar.

Comment: Just linking to your own library or tutorial is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code on how to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212)

Answer (score 0):

I think creating an interpreter for this string would not take too long time.

http://www.industriallogic.com/xp/refactoring/implicitLanguageWithInterpreter.html

here you can find information about design that can be used to create it.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at JINT (Javascript Interpreter for .NET) http://jint.codeplex.com/