# How to create dynamic mathematical function?

Tags: c#, delegates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I evaluate a C# expression dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-sharp-expression-dynamically)

I can do this;

```
int x = 6;
var result = new DataTable().Compute(x + " * 10 / 3", null);
```

And this;

```
public delegate double function(double x);
function func = delegate(double x) { return x * 10 / 3; };
```

So how can i compute like first example and assign it to a delegate like second example?

The goal is doing compute work only once, then use it with many variables.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I evaluate a C# expression dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-sharp-expression-dynamically) and [c# convert string expression to a boolean expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029699/c-sharp-convert-string-expression-to-a-boolean-expression)

Comment: You want an inline delegate and not just a class method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/) for these kind of requirements. For example

```
NCalc.Expression expr = new NCalc.Expression("x * 10 / 3");
expr.EvaluateParameter += (name, args) =>
    {
        if (name == "x" && somecondition == 1) args.Result = 6;
        if (name == "x" && somecondition == 2) args.Result = 12;
    };
var result = expr.Evaluate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create your method (anonymous or not) that utilizes `DataTable.Compute`.

```
Func<double, double> function = x => 
    (double)(new DataTable().Compute(x + " * 10 / 3", null));
```