# evaluate relational operator from a string

Tags: c#, relational-operators

I have relational expressions stored in a database, that i have as strings in an iOS app.  I would like to evaluate the conditions within the strings in C#, similar to the logic in the following psudo code:

```
string str1= "x > 0";
string str2= "y < 1";

int x = 1;
int y=0;

if(str1 && str2)
{
        //do stuff
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029699/c-sharp-convert-string-expression-to-a-boolean-expression

Comment: It really would help if you explained [why you need to do this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377).

Comment: I agree, if they are simple numerical comparisons, and they are related to entities within your database, you could easily just do this in a table, with min max and `enum` to choose  the variable your comparing with and so forth. this could be fast , server side, and easy as a LINQ / EF expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the expressions are simple like the one in the example, then you can simply parse them. But if you have more complex expressions in mind, then I recommend taking a look at C# [Expression Trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/). The documentation does a good job of explaining it.

A much easier method would be to use library like: https://github.com/davideicardi/DynamicExpresso

Comment: Thank You.  It was exactly what I needed

Comment: I am sorry, I had not checked this and did not see your comment.  I marked you as accepted answer just now

Answer (score 0):

Use **Afk Expression** Library ([Afk link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Afk.Expression/))
and try following code it will solve your problem as I sorted out.

**Required NameSpace**

```
using Afk.Expression;
```

**Your code for sending expression as string to library evaluator**

```
string str1 = "x > 0";
    string str2 = "y < 1";

    int x = 10;
    int y = 0;
    var st1=str1.Replace("x",x.ToString());
    var st2 = str2.Replace("y", y.ToString());
    if (Eval(st2) && Eval(st1))
    {
         //checked
    }
```

**Eval Method evaluate mathematical and conditional expression**

```
bool Eval(string st)
{
    ExpressionEval eval = new ExpressionEval(st);
    return Convert.ToBoolean(eval.Evaluate().ToString());
}
```

As well read for more other libraries that you can utilize for your as such problems.