# How to convert string to bool and evaluate the condition?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0

I have to convert a string to bool and evaluate the string condition.
For example:

```
string condition = "8 > 9 || !8";
```

then the condition has to evaluate and return true;

if string condition = "!8"; then condition has to return true.

Suggest me how to evaluate the condition.

Comment: It depends on how reliable the structure of the string is. How many different operators do you expect to have to process?. What code have you written so far?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: it seems like what you're really after here is an runtime expression parser and evaluator; that *isn't really a thing built into .NET* directly, but a range of tools exist. Or depending on the complexity of the expressions you need to parse, it is *usually* relatively easy to write them yourself, if you're used to things like AST evaluation.

Comment: Good exercise for Stack<T>

Comment: btw; it isn't clear to me what `!8` means, as a boolean; is that meant in a C-style "zero is false, non-zero is true" way?

Comment: That's essentially some kind of parser, which will read your equations, determine operators and left/right side operands, have some kind of validation. There is no short answer to that.

Comment: @ste-fu , || , &&, !, <, <=, >, >=  are the operators i have. Upto to now i just resolved the string values in place of 8 and 9.

Comment: I have a condition with registry keys like "REGISTRYVERSION > CURRENTVERSION OR NOT REGISTRYVERSION". I resolved the registry key values like the above condition resolved to 01.00.00.000 > 02.00.00.000 || !01.00.00.000.. Can some one suggest me how to resolve this condition and return bool value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, if you want to evaluate C# code during runtime, you can use 
the .NET Compiler Platform (Roslyn) via the [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting/3.5.0-beta2-final) 
Nuget package.

BTW, I found this right here in stack overflow: [How can I evaluate a C# expression dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53844/how-can-i-evaluate-a-c-sharp-expression-dynamically)

here's a solution to your specific requirement, assuming the only exception to valid C# expressions is treating !8 as boolean true (specifically "!8" preceded or followed followed by any other character is forbidden).

```
private async Task<bool> ProcessExpression(string expression)
    {
        var processedExpression = expression.Replace("!8", "true");
        return await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<bool>(processedExpression);
    }
```

And here's some test code for the above:

```
Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var expresion = "8 > 9";
            var result = await ProcessExpression(expresion);
            Console.WriteLine($"{expresion} : {result}");

            expresion = "8 < 9";
            result = await ProcessExpression(expresion);
            Console.WriteLine($"{expresion} : {result}");

            expresion = "!8";
            result = await ProcessExpression(expresion);
            Console.WriteLine($"{expresion} : {result}");

            expresion = "8 > 9 || !8";
            result = await ProcessExpression(expresion);
            Console.WriteLine($"{expresion} : {result}");

            expresion = "8 > 9 && !8";
            result = await ProcessExpression(expresion);
            Console.WriteLine($"{expresion} : {result}");
        });
```

The output we get is:

8 > 9 : False
8 < 9 : True
!8 : True
8 > 9 || !8 : True
8 > 9 && !8 : False

please note that this solution has a performance penalty and if this is a concert than you should look for other options such as writing a dedicated parser or look for 3rd party Nuget packages.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the IValueConverter interface provided by .net

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter?view=netframework-4.8

Where u define 2 methods Convert and ConvertBack
Each method takes a parameter of type object and return the type object

so u can input the string and return the Boolean.
As for the conversion from a string to expression you can checkout this link 
https://expressiontree-tutorial.net/knowledge-base/5029699/csharp-convert-string-expression-to-a-boolean-expression
which have the required code cleared out.

Comment: it really isn't obvious to me how `IValueConverter` would help here; that just defines an API - but, that isn't the problem here; the problem is implementing it! we could just as well forget about `IValueConverter` and say `bool DoTheThing(string expression) { /* TODO */ }` and we'd be in *exactly* the same position. The second link shown *is* relevant, though.

Comment: I didn't know exactly ur use case so i suggested the IValueConverter so u can use it in several situations like in xaml binding or any other usecase

Comment: this is an old link but it is discussing the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5029699/c-sharp-convert-string-expression-to-a-boolean-expression