# Evaluate string expression and convert to bool?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-3.0

I want to evaluate the string expression and convert the result to bool.

For example

`string expression = !((71 > 70) && (80 > 71)) || 72 < 71 ;`

the above expression has to evaluate and return true.

Can anyone suggest how to evaluate the expression and return bool value?

Comment: You have to use bool. 
bool expression = !((71 > 70) && (80 > 71)) || 72 < 71 ;

Comment: @Jawad No, that one is different

Comment: Seems like you asked the same question a day ago as well .. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60261488/how-to-convert-string-to-bool-and-evaluate-the-condition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont believe there is any built in expression solver that can be leveraged for this kind of expression evaluation. I would recommend [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples) to do the evaluation.

```
string expression = "!((71 > 70) && (80 > 71)) || 72 < 71";
bool output = CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<bool>(expression).Result;
// -> false
```

**Issues with your question**

- The *expression* will not evaluate to true. I dont know why you assume that and require that it does. After the execution of the above script, the resultant bool will be false.

`!((71 > 70) && (80 > 71)) || 72 < 71`
`!((true)    && (true))    || false`
`!(true & true)`
`false`

- you cannot declare a string without quotes; `string express = "within quotes";`. Statement above in post (`string expression = !((71 > 70) && (80 > 71)) || 72 < 71 ;`) is not a valid C# statement.

[Test snippet here at #dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d9y41p)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the NCalc package. The code below produces "False"

```
using System;
using NCalc;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Expression e = new Expression("!((71 > 70) && (80 > 71)) || 72 < 71");
        bool v = (bool)e.Evaluate();
        Console.WriteLine(v.ToString());
    }
}
```

.Net Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/02c5ww

Answer (score -1):

If your requirement is to get expressoin output as string "true" then use this,

```
string expression = Convert.ToString(!((71 > 70) && (80 > 71)) || 72 < 71);
```

And if requirement is to get bool "true" then use this,

```
bool expression = !((71 > 70) && (80 > 71)) || 72 < 71;
```

But your expression is like it will return false, to make it true remove "!" as below,

```
string expression = Convert.ToString(((71 > 70) && (80 > 71)) || 72 < 71);            
bool bool_expression = ((71 > 70) && (80 > 71)) || 72 < 71;
```

Comment: The expression above is a dynamic expression.Then how the string can be converted to bool. I cannot directly assign the expression to bool variable.  bool bool_expression = Convert.ToBoolean(string_expression) did not worked. Any more suggestions?

Comment: Sorry... I didn't read it properly and answered as per example. Good Luck...