# How does LINQPad compile code?

Tags: c#, linqpad

I am guessing it neither invokes csc.exe or implement an entire compiler, so how does it work?

Update: Thanks to Jon Skeet for the pointer to code that was easy to learn from.

```
string c = @"
public class A
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(""hello world"");
    }
}
";

CodeDomProvider compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();

CompilerParameters parameters = new CompilerParameters();
parameters.WarningLevel = 4;
parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;

CompilerResults r = compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, c);

Assembly a = r.CompiledAssembly;

Type[] ts = a.GetTypes();

Type t = ts[0];

object o = t.GetMethod("Main").Invoke(null, new object[] { new string[] { } });
```

Comment: csc.exe, it's what makes System.CodeDom work.  And the IDE.

Comment: @Hans: Well, almost. It would be more accurate to say that both csc.exe and the IDE share a common library that performs code analysis.

Comment: +1 This is a great question and Jon Skeet does it AGAIN!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From ["How LINQPad Works"](http://www.linqpad.net/HowLINQPadWorks.aspx):

> LINQPad compiles your queries using .NET's CSharpCodeProvider (or VBCodeProvider)

Obviously there's rather more to it, but that's the bit you asked about - read the link for more details.

If you want to have a look at a rather more simplistic implementation, you could [download the source code](http://csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx) for Snippy, the little tool I created for C# in Depth. Again, it uses [`CSharpCodeProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) - and it's a simple enough example that it's easy to understand, with any luck. (There are only a few classes involved, IIRC.)

Comment: @AaronAnodide Oh my goodness... IT ALL MAKES SENSE NOW! Mr. Skeet, you have enlightened many SO-ers with your wisdom and we are eternally grateful (if I didn't thank him, I'd probably disappear tonight).

Answer (score 16):

Jon's answer from almost 5 years ago is now out of date.

From ["How LINQPad Works"](http://www.linqpad.net/HowLINQPadWorks.aspx) (as at 29 Jan 2016):

> LINQPad 5 compiles your queries using the **Microsoft Roslyn libraries**
>   (in the past it used .NET's CSharpCodeProvider and VBCodeProvider).

You can see an example of how to use Roslyn to compile your code here: 
[Learn Roslyn Now - Part 16 - The Emit API](https://joshvarty.wordpress.com/2016/01/16/learn-roslyn-now-part-16-the-emit-api/)

Comment: Jon's answer was correct when he wrote it. But then LINQPad 5 came along. It's amazing!